# What is the difference between \let and \def?

Tags: macros, tex-core

What is the difference between the `\let` and `\def` commands in TeX/LaTeX?

Ideally please provide a simple example that will illustrate the difference between them.

Answer (score 281, accepted):

The difference is in the time at which the ‘right hand side’ is evaluated.

Thus `\let\foo\bar` defines `\foo` to have the value that `\bar` had *at the point of definition*. On the other hand, `\def\foo{\bar}` in effect defines `\foo` to have the value that `\bar` has *at the point of use*.

Consider:

```
\def\bar{hello}
\let\fooi\bar
\def\fooii{\bar}
\fooi +\fooii

\def\bar{goodbye}
\fooi +\fooii
```

This produces

```
hello+hello
hello+goodbye
```

---

This is a simple process.

However it's also a subtle one, so it might be worth highlighting a few key points:

- When TeX encounters control sequences such as `\fooi`, it evaluates them; if these are macros (that is, they have been defined by `\def`, or `\let` equal to something which was defined by `\def`), then the result is that they will *expand* to other tokens, which TeX will then examine in turn, and so on, recursively, until what's left is either ‘primitive’ control sequences or letters (I'm simplifying a little bit).
- `\fooi` expands directly to the characters `hello` (because `\bar` initially did, and `\fooi` was defined to have the same *value*).
- `\fooii`, in contrast, expands to `\bar`, *which is then immediately reexamined and reexpanded*.  In the first case, `\bar` expands to `hello` and in the second case to `goodbye`.  The definition of `\fooii` hasn't changed, but `\bar` has been redefined in between.
- Getting a clear idea of the process of this recursive expansion is *very* helpful when learning how to develop and debug TeX macros.

Comment: Does this mean that `\let\foo\bar` is the same as `\def\foo{\expandafter\bar}`? Probably not, but why then?

Comment: With that definition, writing `\foo\alpha` at the bottom of the example would expand into `\expandafter\bar\alpha`; what that does is first expand `\alpha`, and _then_ expand `\bar` (in this case to 'goodbye'). Using `\expandafter` counts as pretty advanced TeX, and is for the arcane cases where you need to control the order of evaluation in a non-default way.  Try TeXing `\def\baz{wibble} \def\x#1{-#1-} \x\baz \expandafter\x\baz`

Comment: The closest analogue to `\let\foo\bar` along the lines @Didii is suggesting would be `\expandafter\def\expandafter\foo\expandafter{\bar}`. There remain differences even between these, as detailed in Martin Scharrer's answer. But for most purposes, I think they would have much the same effect.

Comment: [Here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/8165/3627) is some more discussion.

Comment: Awesome answer. I guess its a bit like assignment vs reference in other languages....

Comment: @NicholasHamilton It's a similar idea, yes, but that may be a slightly confusing way to think about it, since TeX is rather _sui generis_ in programming language terms. A useful mental model is that TeX macros expand, and the expansion is than expanded, and... so on until the engine arrives at one of the relatively small number of primitives which actually _do_ something, such as adding a box (possibly containing a letter or a paragraph) to a list of boxes. Lower-level TeX programming, and its headaches, is all about controlling what gets expanded when, and to what.

Comment: For the last few weeks, `tex-core` and related tag questions have been modified and plopped up on the main site. There is also a Wikibook on TeX that needs some attention and one on LaTeX that needs even more attention.

Comment: I searched for it to try to understand the topic better.  I guess this question is really fundamental, and therefore likely to be revisited.  Is this a good thing, that `tex-core` tag questions are being modified and "plopped up"?

Comment: Thanks for your contributions, @a-feldman, but I'm not convinced they really clarify things. The underlying expansion idea is at heart very simple, and this was (deliberately) emphasised by the brevity of the answer. I have drafted similar remarks in the past, but on reflection deleted them from my edit before saving: I've redone this now in response to your implied request for expansion of the answer.

Comment: Thanks both for your original answer, which helped me better understand this very important topic., and for your expansion of your answer.

Answer (score 52):

While the existing answers are all true I like to highlight one point which wasn't explicitly mentioned yet.
I myself got this information recently from Joseph Wright (see his answer and our comments in [Simple un-obfuscation of some LaTeX internals](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11795/simple-un-obfuscation-of-some-latex-internals/11801#11801)).

As Michael said `\let\macroa\macrob` "copies" the definition of `\macrob` to `\macroa`. However an IMHO important thing here is that the definition isn't actually copied, i.e. exists twice, but the command sequence `\macroa` now points to the same [hash table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) entry as `\macrob`.
This means that `\let\macroa\macrob` uses less memory space (very important in the early days but not anymore) and is faster then `\def\macroa{\macrob}` because in the second form *two* command sequence names have to be resolved in the hash table.

Also `\let` actually "copies" the definition of *tokens*, which do not need to be macros/command sequences. This allows the definition of command sequences representing implicit characters like `\let\bgroup={`.

Comment: According to the TeXbook p. 269, the `\bgroup` control sequence doesn't “represent” an implicit character; it *is* an implicit character (by definition of implicit characters).

Comment: @frougon: Not sure what your exact point is here. I don't see a real difference between *represents* and *is* in this context. I could also have written "makes it an implicit character" or similar. Keep in mind that not all users here are native English speakers.

Comment: No offense intended, I myself am not a native English speaker. “Represents” implies “is not really”, IMHO. But here, `\bgroup` is really what DEK calls an implicit character, there is no indirection to follow in order to get from `\bgroup` to an implicit character.

Answer (score 26):

They're pretty completely different. `\let` copies a command to a new name, while `\def` creates a new command.

For example:

```
\def \foo {bar}
```

creates a new command `\foo`, that evaluates to `bar` when run.

```
\let \foo \bar
```

copies the commands from the `\bar` commands to the `\foo` command, so you can call either. Because it's a copy (and not a pointer from one to the other), redefining `\foo` won't change the behavior of `\baz`. Hence:

```
\def \foo {bar}
\let \baz \foo
\baz % Outputs 'bar'
\def \foo {new-definition}
\baz % Still outputs 'bar'
```

Comment: Your \def statements are missing braces, and remember that unless 'bar' is a primitive then TeX expands the material rather then executing it. Good answer, though: more or less what I've have put.

Comment: @Joseph Ah yes, fixed; I never actually use `\def`, so I'm not surprised I botched the syntax :)

Comment: 'pretty completely'... lol, why don't you say 'pretty almost sometimes definately always partially never certainly similar but different'