# What is the difference between \def and \newcommand?

Tags: macros

Inspired by a [question about `\let` and `\def`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/258/what-is-the-difference-between-let-and-def), I have some that essentially all boil down to asking

**What are the differences between `\def` and `\newcommand`?**

In particular, I wonder

1. Is it possible to have parameters passed to `\def`ed commands, both optional and required?
2. Is there a `\redef` command equivalent to `\renewcommand`?
3. I have only ever used `\newcommand` -- is there any reason I should change that habit?

but I welcome comments on anything else I may not have thought of in this list!

Answer (score 281, accepted):

`\def` is a TeX primitive, `\newcommand` is a LaTeX overlay on top of `\def`.  The most obvious benefits of `\newcommand` over `\def` are:

1. `\newcommand` checks whether or not the command already exists
2. `\newcommand` allows you to define an optional argument

In general, anything that `\newcommand` does can be done by `\def`, but it usually involves a little trickery and unless you want something that `\newcommand` can't do, there's no point in reinventing the wheel.

In answer to your particular points:

1. Yes and No.  A command defined using `\def` has to know exactly what its options are, and how they will be presented to it.  However, a TeX command can be a bit clever and examine things *other* than its arguments.  The way that optional commands are handled is to look at the next character in the stream and if it is `[` then one version of the command is called, whereas if it isn't then another is called.  So if you're prepared to do some hackery, then optional arguments are possible via `\def`, but it isn't half so easy as `\newcommand`.
2. No.  Since `\def` doesn't check for a command already being defined, you can redefine stuff simply using `\def` again.  To get the checking, you need to use the `\@ifundefined` command (note the ampersat (`@`) sign!).
3. No!

There's probably lots more to be said on the differences, but that's enough from me.

Comment: I'd add that `\newcommand` can't make anything starting `\end...`. This is because LaTeX uses these names for the end of environments, and wants to 'discourage' you from breaking things.

Comment: @SamB: looking at the man page, probably.  Although in connection with "brains", the word "upgrade" makes me think of Cybermen.  As I live in the same country as Bad Wolf Bay, I like to steer clear of such things as much as possible.

Answer (score 134):

Adding to [Andrew's](#658) already good response, the one thing that `\def` can do that `\newcommand` cannot is define commands that take delimiters other than braces. For example, if you want to be able to write `\foo<hello>` and have the ‘hello’ interpreted as an argument, you can write

```
\def\foo<#1>{...something with #1...}
```

You can also have commands that read input up to the *next* brace, such as

```
\def\foobar#1#{\framebox[#1]}
\foobar 47pt {hello}
```

---

For a combination of the extensibility of `\def` with the ease-of-use of `\newcommand`, check out David Kastrup's `suffix` package. Very handy when you want to define custom markup for your document.

Also look at the LaTeX3 package `xparse` which takes a more structured and generalised look at how `\newcommand` should work.

Answer (score 70):

Here is a summary of the main points made by the other answers. In each case, click on the ▶ symbols for more details.

- `\newcommand` is part of LaTeX; `\def` is part of TeX. [[▶](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/658/25356)]
- `\newcommand` fails if the command is already defined; `\def` doesn't. [[▶](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/658/25356)]
- `\newcommand` provides a convenient syntax for specifying the number of arguments, and specifying a (single) optional argument; `\def` enables pattern-matching on the form of its arguments, which makes it more general but also less readable. [[▶](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/662/25356)]
- `\newcommand` can't define a command whose name starts with "end"; `\def` can. [[▶](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/62266/25356)]
- `\newcommand` defines "long" commands; `\def` (unless `\long\def` is used) defines short ones. (The arguments of a "long" command can include paragraph breaks.) [[▶](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/115941/25356)]

Comment: I thought I would add this summary because there is no single "definitive" answer here; there are instead several good points raised in different answers.

Answer (score 46):

One quite important difference, not mentioned in the discussion so far, is:

- `\newcommand\foo{...}` corresponds to `\long\def\foo{...}`
- `\newcommand*\foo{...}` corresponds to `\def\foo{...}`

What does `\long` mean? Well, if `\myCommand` is defined using `\long`, then its arguments can contain paragraph breaks, like this:

```
\myCommand{Lorem ipsum

dolor sit 

amet.}
```

If `\myCommand` were defined without `\long`, then the code above would generate an error. The idea is, that if you *know* that your command won't ever need to take arguments containing paragraph breaks, then defining it without `\long` helps you to catch some situations where you've forgotten a closing brace.

For more in-depth discussion: [What's the difference between \newcommand and \newcommand*?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1050/whats-the-difference-between-newcommand-and-newcommand)

---

**Slight digression.** Here is a little example that highlights this particular difference between `\newcommand` and `\def`.

The following code prints **Not empty** ...

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\newcommand\foo{}
\ifx\foo\empty Empty\else Not empty\fi
\end{document}
```

... but if you swap `\newcommand` for `\def`, it would print **Empty**! This phenomenon has been explained in [a comment by Qrrbrbirlbel](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/115937/what-is-the-difference-between-def-and-newcommand-part-ii#comment256814_115937). The `\empty` command is created using `\def\empty{}`. Then, the `\foo` command is created (via `\newcommand`) using `\long\def\foo{}`. The presence of the `\long` stops these definitions being equal, and thus makes the test in the conditional fail.

Comment: Hi John. A tip: if you directly paste the url of a question/answer, the title will automatically appear.

Answer (score 18):

One subtle difference is that you cannot define commands starting with `end`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}

\newcommand\test{}
\newcommand\endtest{}

\begin{document}
  \begin{test}
  \end{test}
\end{document}
```

results in

```
! LaTeX Error: Command \endtest already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.
```

You can always use `\newenvironment` to achieve this. But the above code doesn't work even when using `\providecommand` instead of `\newcommand`.

[Why is there no \provideenvironment?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/56667/8057) According to Frank Mittelbach, it's performance considerations -- saving memory, 20 years ago. But now there's `\ProvideDocumentEnvironment` from the `xparse` package. Plus,

> Unlike LaTeX 2ε’s \newcommand and relatives, the \DeclareDocumentCommand
>   function do not prevent creation of functions with names starting \end.

Comment: Interesting that LaTeX reports `\endtest already defined` when using `\newcommand`, but with `renewcommand` the message is `\endtest undefined`.  I didn't know that LaTeX suffers from schizophrenia. :-)