# What's the difference between \newcommand and \newcommand*?

Tags: macros, starred-version

I just spotted someone use `\newcommand*` in an answer and realised that I'd never quite sorted out in my head what the star (asterisk) was there for.

(This one is practically impossible to search for on the internet so this is a good place to record the answer!)

Comment: so much for a self-documenting system, huh? texdoc fail =) i thought it can do that.

Answer (score 544, accepted):

A bit of background first. When Knuth wrote TeX, he realised that most macros would not need to absorb more than one paragraph as an argument. As a result, a good way to test for errors such as a missing `}` is to forbid macros to accept paragraph tokens (either those generated by blank lines or explicit `\par` tokens). So he created `\def` for definitions which cannot take a paragraph token, and the `\long` prefix to allow them to:

```
\def\examplea#1{% #1 cannot contain \par
}
\long\def\exampleb#1{% #1 can contain \par
}
```

When LaTeX was written, Lamport created `\newcommand` as a wrapper around `\def` with various bits of error checking. He found that paragraph tokens can pop up in odd places. So he decided that `\newcommand` would be 'long'. When the LaTeX team took over for LaTeX2e, they decided that you would need to add the modifier `*` to prevent this:

```
\newcommand{\examplea}[1]{% #1 can contain \par
}
\newcommand*{\exampleb}[1]{% #1 cannot contain \par
}
```

Most of the time, `\newcommand*` is the best choice as you want the error-checking that it provides. That is why examples given by experienced LaTeX users normally use this form, rather than just `\newcommand`.

The same behaviour is seen with `\newenvironment`:

```
\newenvironment{examplea}[1]{% #1 can contain \par
}{}
\newenvironment*{exampleb}[1]{% #1 cannot contain \par
}{}
```

This works by defining `\examplea` and `\endexamplea` more-or-less using `\newcommand`, and `\exampleb` and `\endexampleb` more-or-less using `\newcommand*`. As a result, the 'end' macros have the same 'long' status as the 'begin' ones, even though they never take arguments. (Note that this does not affect what can go into the *body* of the environment, only the *arguments* at the start.) Environments are covered in more detail in [What is the difference between \newenvironment and \newenvironment*?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86449/what-is-the-difference-between-newenvironment-and-newenvironment).

For LaTeX3, we've decided to take a somewhat hybrid approach. If you use `xparse` for defining document commands, they are only 'long' if you ask for it:

```
\NewDocumentCommand\examplea{m}{% #1 cannot contain \par
}
\NewDocumentCommand\examplab{+m}{% #1 can contain \par
}
```

(We've decided on `+` to represent a long argument). On the other hand, for internal use it is normally best to accept paragraph tokens, and to leave the filtering to the user interface level.

Comment: So what’s the common/best practice for macros without arguments?

Comment: A very good question. I favour making macros long only when needed, so use `\newcommand*`/`\def` for macros with no arguments. However, it does not matter for the application of the macro. One place it _does_ matter is when you do an `\ifx` test: identical macros with no arguments but where one is long and the other is not do not evaluate to 'identical' as far a TeX is concerned.

Comment: Thanks. But I’ve just noticed that it cannot (easily?) be used with `\WithSuffix` or `\expandafter`. :-( Or is there an obvious way around this?

Comment: I don't know about `\WithSuffix` (I'd use `xparse` instead), but `\expandafter\newcommand\expandafter*\csname some-name\endcsname{}` works fine. Remember that we go past one token with `\expandafter`.

Comment: Thanks. For the record, to make it work with `\WithSuffix`, it’s sufficient to put the whole defining command in braces, i.e. `{\newcommand*}`. As for `xparse`, one of these days I’ll learn its usage but for now I’m still struggling with the basics of TeX.

Comment: We're hoping that `xparse` means most people have less basic TeX to learn :-)

Comment: The starred variant of `\newcommand` wasn't introduced by Lamport but by the LaTeX2e team with the LaTeX2e release 1994/12/01. (see `usrguide`)

Comment: In LuaMetaTeX, Hans completely removed the code path for non-`\long` macros and made `\long` a no-op.

Answer (score 89):

According to the 2nd Edition of *the LaTeX Companion*: (p. 846):

> [`\newcommand*`] defines a [command], that is not, in TeX terms, long. This means that the newly defined command does not accept empty lines or `\par`.

This is also the default behaviour of `\def`, while the unstarred version is actually equivalent to `\long\def`.

Answer (score 34):

From [here](http://tug.org/mail-archives/texhax/2005-March/003732.html): "Using the starred version of `\newcommand` means that the arguments of the defined command cannot contain a blank line or `\par`. This makes it a lot easier to spot runaway arguments."

Answer (score 20):

In the Latex2e for authors (usrguide.pdf) I found section 3.4 relating about all "defin-y" commands:

> All the above five ‘defining commands’ now have *-forms that are usually the
>           better form to use when defining commands with arguments, unless any of these
>             arguments is intended to contain whole paragraphs of text. Moreover, if you ever 
>             do find yourself needing to use the non-star form then you should ask whether 
>               that argument would not better be treated as the contents of a suitably defined 
>                 environment.