# LyX: modify thesis.cls preamble

Tags: lyx, preamble, thesis

I'm using LyX and a custom class from [Colorado-Boulder](http://amath.colorado.edu/documentation/LaTeX/thesis/) which is based on the [`thesis`](http://ctan.sqsol.co.uk/help/Catalogue/entries/thesis.html) class.  I'm at another school and my advisor wants me to include titles of the readers on the signature page as well as a date line for each signator.  I've looked through some documentation on the `thesis` class and poked around in the `.cls` file in use but didn't come across anything obvious to change.  Perhaps this section would help though?

```
\newcommand*{\th@degreeyear}{\number\the\year}
\newcommand*{\th@signature}[1]{ \begin{center}
    \normalsize
    \vspace*{16mm}  % works well?
    \vrule width 80mm height 0.2mm\\
    #1 \end{center}
}
\newcommand*{\th@dateline}{
\vspace*{9mm}
\begin{flushright}
    Date~{\vrule width 35mm height 0.2mm}
\end{flushright}
```

How do I include this?

Answer (score 2):

- If you would like to change existing macros of a class file, you can use `\renewcommand` to redefine them.
- If you see the character `@` in the code, i.e. in macro names, use need to use `\makeatletter` before and `\makeatother` after. See why: [What do \makeatletter and \makeatother do](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8351/what-do-makeatletter-and-makeatother-do).
- In LyX, use the menu and go to document settings, to modify the document preamble. Insert the lines for redefinition there. These may now look like

  ```
  \makeatletter
  \renewcommand*{\th@signature}[1]{%
    \begin{center}
    ...
    \end{center}%
  }
  \makeatother
  ```

An explanation for the star `*` is given here: [What's the difference between \newcommand and \newcommand*](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1050/whats-the-difference-between-newcommand-and-newcommand). And for the percent signs: [What is the use of percent signs at the end of lines](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7453/what-is-the-use-of-percent-signs-at-the-end-of-lines).