# How can I modify the preamble in Lyx?

Tags: lyx, preamble, blank-page

I am using Lyx and need to modify my document's preamble. Where should I add

```
\documentclass[openany]{scrbook}
\usepackage{classicthesis}

\begin{document}

\chapter{A}
```

in order to remove blank pages from the document?

I would like to know the file name and the specific place in the file.

Comment: your question is very unclear. a document can only have one `\documentclass` line and it has to be at the start of the file. the filename is whatever filename your document has.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. I have edited your question to make the content and format clearer. If you think I've misunderstood your intentions, feel free to revert my changes.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I think the question is really: how can I modify the preamble of a document in Lyx?

Comment: Perhaps [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/19155/39222) is helpful? It includes information about how to edit the preamble your document uses in LyX.