# No space following macro without argument

Tags: macros, spacing, xspace

With a macro such as:

```
\def\naive{na\"{\i}ve}
```

I find that the space which I would hope to follow it, is absent. So, with

```
the \naive approach
```

I get

> the naïveapproach

in the output. How do I bring back the space?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The problem of using `\naive\` or `\naive{}`: If you happen to forget the closing backslash/braces, you'll end with gobbled space without noticing it.

The problem of adding `\xspace` to a macro's definition: This may produce inconsistent spacing if the macro uses `\emph`. See [xspace and italic correction](https://groups.google.com/group/comp.text.tex/browse_thread/thread/1f10f4498aa80a9f) for details.

In the thread linked above, Will Robertson suggested to use "delimited" macros (e.g. with `/` at the end) as an alternative. The main advantage of `\naive/` is that an error message will occur if you happen to forget the closing slash.

(See also the comments to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/553/what-packages-do-people-load-by-default-in-latex/1103#1103) answer.)

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\naive}{}% To make sure that \naive isn't already defined    
\def\naive/{na\"{\i}ve}

\begin{document}

the \naive/ approach

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: the `\newcommand` should be a  `\providecommand` and then you can use a `\renewcommand`

Comment: @Herbert: a) I want TeX to throw an error, not to silently overwrite an existing definition, so it's `\newcommand` for me. b) AFAIK, `\renewcommand` doesn't work for delimited macros.

Comment: no, then it should be `\@ifdefinable{...}`

Comment: @Herbert: I don't know `\@ifdefinable{...}`, why is it better?

Comment: then you can out a message in the text, which the user understand!

Answer (score 15):

Use the package [`xspace`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xspace). It

> provides a single command that looks at what comes after it in the
>   command stream, and decides whether to insert a space to replace one
>   "eaten" by the TeX command decoder.

For your case it can be used as in the following:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xspace}

\def\naive{na\"{\i}ve\xspace}

\begin{document}

the \naive approach

\end{document}
```

Comment: Also, I would suggest using `\newcommand` instead of `\def`. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1050/whats-the-difference-between-newcommand-and-newcommand

Comment: Just for reference: [Drawbacks of xspace](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/86565/4918).

Answer (score 6):

Use braces `\naive{}` or `\naive\`  or `xspace`. See the FAQ: https://texfaq.org/FAQ-xspace

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that the follwing space is uses as macro end. Type `\navie{}` or use the `xspace` package.

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{xspace}
\newcomand{\naiv}{naiv\xspace}

\begin{document}
Test \naiv Test.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Just for reference: [Drawbacks of xspace](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/86565/4918).

Answer (score 3):

Quick answer:
    the `\naive\` approach

Better answer: Use the `xspace`-package

```
\usepackage{xspace}
\newcommand{\better\xspace }
...

the \better approach
```

Advantage: `xspace` take a look on the next character. So you have not an obsolete space in:

```
Macro at sentence end\better.
```

Comment: Just for reference: [Drawbacks of xspace](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/86565/4918).

Answer (score 3):

A dirty trick: Use a special character in the macro name (not working with `\newcommand`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\¶naive{na\"{\i}ve}
\begin{document}
the \¶naive approach
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE]

Note: Do no start another macro with the same special character, although is possible use again this character in another position.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know `xspace` package but I mean that it does somethig similar to this:

```
\def\maybespacelist{.,;!?}
\def\maybespace{\let\nexxt=\space 
   \edef\maybespaceA{\noexpand\maybespaceB\maybespacelist\relax}%
   \futurelet\next\maybespaceA
}
\def\maybespaceB#1{\ifx#1\relax \nexxt \else \ifx#1\next \let\nexxt=\relax\fi
   \expandafter\maybespaceB\fi
}
\protected\def\naive{na\"{\i}ve\maybespace}

The \naive approach. The approach is \naive.

\bye
```

Answer (score 3):

For completeness, you could also define the macro as

```
\def\naive#{na\"{\i}ve}
```

which will *require* that it be followed by `{}` when ever it is used. For example, `the \naive{} approach` will work whereas `the \naive approach` will raise an error which says `Use of \naive doesn't match its definition.`.

See page 204 of The TEXbook for details. Also, [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/290504/89497) may be of interest.