# Why don't I get any space after \thepage?

Tags: macros, spacing

The code `\thepage of` yields the output `3of`.

I can fix it by writing `\thepage~of`, but what causes this in the first place? I can't imagine when it would be useful.

Comment: Spaces after control sequences are ignored (if they aren't of the form `\<nonalphabetic>`, like `\!`).

Comment: @egreg: Aha. What is the proper way of adding breakable spaces after control sequences?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

A TeX macro 'eats' the white space after it, so `\TeX nician` is typeset as TeXnician, and `\thepage of` is typeset as `3of`.  You can either type `\thepage~of`, or `\thepage\ of`, or `\thepage{} of`.  In the first case the space is unbreakable, in the others it is not.

Update:  if you *need* space after macros for any reason, try `xspace` package:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{xspace}
\newcommand{\Thepage}{\thepage\xspace}
\begin{document}
\Thepage of one.  The page is \Thepage.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The space is stretchable in all cases. Non stretchable space is achieved only with `\kern`. With the default meaning of `\thepage` the results of `\thepage\ of` and `\thepage{} of` are exactly the same under all circumstances (if the space factor of digits and letters isn't changed). They may be different if the expansion of `\thepage` ends with a period, say, or another character having space factor different from 1000. (Note: there is actually a *very* small difference if `\thepage` is defined to give `\Alph{page}`, as uppercase letters have space factor 999.)

Comment: @egreg: Many thanks, I was already wondering if there was a difference.

Answer (score 13):

Suppose spaces after control sequences *wouldn't* be ignored. In that case, how would you achieve the output `3of` if you so desired? You can't write `\thepageof` because that would be, well, a control sequence with different name. :-)

That's why spaces after (alphabetic) control sequences *are* ignored. If you *want* a space, write `\thepage\ of` or `\thepage{} of`. (`\thepage~of` is only correct if you don't want a line break after `\thepage`.)

Comment: `\thepage{}of` :) But I see the benefit now that I know it goes for all control sequences.

Comment: Or `\thepage\unskip of`

Comment: Some people also write `{\thepage} of` which also works, but it IMHO strange. Then you could also use `\thepage\space of`, which is useful in expandable context where you don't like `{}` or any macro like ``\ `` or `~`, like if you write to files.

Comment: I think we all agree that Knuth chose the most practical solution. ;-)

Comment: Actually, `xspace` package allows one to define macros that have spaces after them if needed.  Try, for example `\usepackage{xspace} \newcommand{\Thepage}{\thepage\xspace}`, and then  typeset `\Thepage of one.  The page is \Thepage.`.

Comment: @Boris: I don't like `xspace` -- see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25820/no-space-following-macro-without-argument

Comment: @lockstep I do not commonly use `xspace`, but another tool in a toolbox sometimes might be handy.  And, of course, it is always a pleasure to study David's and Morten's code.

Answer (score 9):

For reference (and DEK entertainment), from the [TeX Book](http://mirrors.ctan.org/systems/knuth/dist/tex/texbook.tex) (chapter **3 Controlling TeX**, p 8):

> It is usually unnecessary for you to use “control space,” since
>   control sequences aren't often needed at the ends of words. But here's
>   an example that might shed some light on the matter: This manual
>   itself has been typeset by TeX, and one of the things that occurs
>   fairly often is the tricky logo `\TeX`, which requires backspacing and
>   lowering the E. There's a special control word
>
> ```
> \TeX
> ```
>
> that produces the half-dozen or so instructions necessary to typeset
>   `\TeX`. When a phrase like `\TeX\ ignores spaces after control words.`
>   is desired, the manuscript renders it as follows:
>
> ```
> TeX ignores spaces after control words.
> ```
>
> Notice the extra `\` following `\TeX`; this produces the control space
>   that is necessary because TeX ignores spaces after control words.
>   Without this extra `\`, the result would have been
>
> ```
> TeXignores spaces after control words.
> ```
>
> On the other hand, you can't simply put `\` after `\TeX` in all
>   contexts. For example, consider the phrase
>
> ```
> the logo `TeX'.
> ```
>
> In this case an extra backslash doesn't work at all; in fact, you get
>   a curious result if you type
>
> ```
> the logo `\TeX\'.
> ```
>
> Can you guess what happens? Answer: The `\'` is a control sequence
>   denoting an acute accent, as in our `P\'olya` example above; the
>   effect is therefore to put an accent over the next nonblank character,
>   which happens to be a period. In other words, you get an accented
>   period,...
>
> Computers are good at following instructions, but not at reading your
>   mind.