# Should spaces be placed after every special character input command in ConTeXT?

Tags: spacing, context, characters

I am using several special character commands, such as those described at [Which symbols need to be escaped in ConTeXt?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48933/which-symbols-need-to-be-escaped-in-context). I noticed that some, such as `\textdollar` will not work if they are immediately followed by some other word, e.g.:

```
\textbraceleftThis is some text.\textbraceright
```

To fix this, I have added some spaces after the command:

```
\textbraceleft This is some text.\textbraceright
```

- Is it correct to always place spaces after these commands? Are there any cases where this will create problems, such as a line break when the two items should be placed together?
- Are the `\#` and `\&` treated differently?

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37955/why-dont-i-get-any-space-after-thepage

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the meaning of `\textbraceleft`, in the sense that this is a rule valid for *all* macros (or more generally, control sequences).

TeX scanning of a control word ends with the first nonletter. The first example you give is the control word `\textbraceleftThis` which is probably undefined.

On the other hand, `\#` is *not* a control word, because the backslash is followed by a nonletter. By rule it is a control symbol and the scanning ends there: only one nonletter can be part of the command's name. Therefore

```
\#text
```

will give

> #test

while

```
\# text
```

will give

> # test

with a space.

A space after a control *word* is ignored. Not after a control symbol. This is one of the first rules one learns with TeX.

Weren't for this rule, one couldn't have macros

```
\a \ab \abc \abcd \abcde
```

which are instead possible and all with unrelated meanings.