# How can I avoid extra whitespace after using a macro before punctuation?

Tags: macros, spacing, punctuation

I have a document in which certain frequently-occurring entity names are replaced with macros, e.g.:

```
\newcommand{\entity}{\emph{Name of Entity}}
...
Lorem ipsum dolor sit \entity, consequat consectetur.
```

If I define the command like this I get correct formatting if `\entity` is immediately followed by punctuation (as above) but incorrect formatting otherwise (e.g. `Lorem \entity ipsum` becomes "Lorem Name of Entityipsum"). If I include the space in the definition of `\entity` (note space between closing brackets):

```
\newcommand{\entity}{\emph{Name of Entity} }
```

I get the opposite behaviour, proper spacing only when not followed by punctuation.

I assume there's some magick command I'm not including in the macro to achieve something sensible?

Comment: Have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25820/no-space-following-macro-without-argument

Comment: lockstep's link is good; you want to look at the answer that suggests `\xspace`.

Comment: @lockstep -- `\xspace` is exactly what I'm after, thanks. Would you care to add that as an answer so I can mark it accepted?

Comment: @Doches It seems nobody but me likes the "delimited macro" approach. ;-)

Comment: @lockstep -- `\xspace` doesn't work with plain tex.  we oldtimers really do prefer a trailing backslash or a grouped `{\command}`, but we're a dwindling minority.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although I personally prefer the "delimited macro" approach described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/25825/510), you will probably want to use the `\xspace` macro provided by the [package of the same name](http://ctan.org/pkg/xspace).

Answer (score 4):

Put a backslash or an empty group after `\entity` when you want a space.

```
\newcommand{\entity}{\emph{Name of Entity}}
...
Lorem \entity\ ipsum
Lorem \entity{} ipsum
```

Comment: That *works*, but I'd greatly prefer a way to make the macro behave sensibly that doesn't require me to manually encode spaces.

Comment: You could put the "\ " in the command declaration of course if you know that you _always_ want the space there...

Comment: That's the problem I'm trying to solve, @jonalv -- I would like to use the same macro with and without a following space, and would like LaTeX to figure out which is which. If I define `\entity` as `\newcommand{\entity}{\emph{Name of Entity} }` I also get this behaviour ("\ " seems equivalent in command definitions to " ").