# How do I get microtype's "outer spacing" to work with the xspace package?

Tags: spacing, microtype, letterspacing, xspace

`Microtype` adds extra space to the start and end of letterspaced text, configured via the `\SetTracking` command's "outer spacing" option.  Unfortunately, `xspace` breaks this.  For example, I define a few macros for acronyms:

```
\newcommand{\foo}[0]{\textsc{foo}\xspace}
```

The result of typesetting the text "bar \foo bar" now turns out lopsided: there is more space before "FOO" than after.  Anyone know of a good workaround for this?

The following document adds lots of outer spacing to demonstrate the problem more clearly:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[tracking]{microtype}
\SetTracking
  [outer spacing={2000*,,}]
  {encoding=*, shape={sc,scit}}
  {100}
\usepackage{xspace}
\newcommand{\foo}[0]{\textsc{foo}\xspace}
\begin{document}

bar \foo bar

bar \textsc{foo} bar

\end{document}
```

This prints

```
"bar      foo bar"
```

in the first paragraph, and

```
"bar      foo      bar"
```

in the second.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).  While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using `\xspace`, you can use the trick with a terminating `slash` in the definition:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[tracking]{microtype}
\SetTracking
  [outer spacing={2000*,,}]
  {encoding=*, shape={sc,scit}}
  {100}

\newcommand{\newfoo}{}% In case `\newfoo` is defined 
\def\newfoo/{\textsc{newfoo}}

\begin{document}

bar \textsc{foo} bar

bar \newfoo/ bar

\end{document}
```

See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/25825/9632.

Answer (score 3):

This has been fixed in [microtype](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/microtype/microtype.pdf) v2.5a (after a mere eleven months...).