# Declare macro for simple text snippets

Tags: macros

I want to use something like this:

```
\newcommand{\favouritealgorithm}{\texttt{Gaussian elimination}}
```

so that

```
My favourite algorithm is \favouritealgorithm written in C.
```

produces

```
My favourite algorithm is \texttt{Gaussian elimination} written in C.
```

However, the space after the word "elimination" is omitted. Which macro provides the correct behaviour?

Comment: This has been asked several times: see http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31091/3954 or http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/25825/3954.

Comment: You can write `My favourite algorithm is \favouritealgorithm\ written in C.`

Comment: you could use the [xspace](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xspace) package and add `\xspace` at the end of your definition.

Comment: or you could surround your invocation in braces, as in `is {\favoritealgorithm} wr...`