# How to redefine the section symbol (§)?

Tags: symbols

I'm trying to redefine the section symbol (§) so that it automatically places a space after it. When inserting the symbol in text, I typically write `\S{} Section Number` which gets me the spacing between the `§` and the `Section Number` that I'm after. Since I do this *every single time* I figured I'd just redefine the command.

Here is my attempt:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\let\OldS\S
\renewcommand{\S}{\OldS{}}

\begin{document}

\S 13

\OldS 13

\S{} 13

\OldS{} 13

\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't seem that I've changed the behavior of `\S` at all--- both `\S` and `\OldS` seem to behave identically.

Why doesn't my attempt produce the desired space between `\S` and the following text and how can I fix it?

Comment: Perhaps you want `\renewcommand{\S}{\OldS\ }`?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [No space following macro without argument](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25820/5764). You can use [`xspace`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xspace), but also read [Drawbacks of `xspace`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/86565/5764).

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Works perfectly! If you turn that into an answer (maybe with a short explanation of why that works and my attempt doesn't, if possible) I'd be happy to accept so you get the credit.

Comment: My guess is that the extra backslah stops the extra space at the end from being gobbled?

Comment: @Werner Now you have me worried about using `xspace`. Is it something that a relative novice shouldn't tinker with?

Comment: @Dennis: If you *mostly* use `\S` with a space, you can use it as such and add `\unskip` wherever you want to remove the space (as in `\S\unskip`). If you *mostly* use `\S` without a space, then you can add the space manually. As a novice, I would suggest using `xspace` and see if it suits your needs.

Comment: Normally in LaTeX almost all numbering should be automatic (in case the problem of marking up the space between the symbol and the number would not arise) How come you are having to number by hand?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle It's for putting in references to sections and ranges of sections in the post-note of natbib style `\citep` parenthetical citations. Writing `(Author, §1.1 -- 1.3)` doesn't look as nice to me as writing `(Author, § 1.1 -- 1.3)`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The command `\S` is defined with `\DeclareRobustCommand`, so redefining it with `\renewcommand` is not the best strategy, see [When to use \LetLtxMacro?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88001/when-to-use-letltxmacro)

If you *really* want a space after `\S` (which is not usual, I should say), it's better to act at a lower level.

The kernel definition of `\S` is

```
% latex.ltx, line 1798:
\DeclareRobustCommand{\S}{\ifmmode\mathsection\else\textsection\fi}
```

so a better strategy would be

```
\usepackage{xspace}

\let\S\relax % to avoid spurious warnings
\DeclareRobustCommand{\S}{%
  \ifmmode
    \mathsection
  \else
    \textsection~%
  \fi
}
```

You surely don't want a line break after §, do you? So `~` is necessary. Using `\xspace` doesn't guarantee that a line break is not taken at the space.

---

Note. With

```
\let\OldS\S
\renewcommand{\S}{\OldS\ }
```

an `\S` command that ends up in a caption or other moving argument will result in *two* spaces. Why?

When LaTeX writes in the `.aux` file a command `\S 1` appearing in a figure caption, it will write

\protect \S  \ 1

because the expansion of `\OldS` is still `\protect\S`. The same would be written out in the `.lof` file. When the `.lof` file is read in, `\protect` will be ignored, and `\S` will be interpreted normally as `\OldS\`; this means *two* spaces, because the following `\` would still be there.

---

For having “double §”, you can do

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\NS}{%
  \textsection\@ifnextchar\NS{}{~}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\NS 1 and \NS\NS 2--3

\end{document}
```

reserving `\S` for the cases where you don't want a space (I can't see when, though).

However, I believe that the simplest way is to type

```
\S~1 and \S\S~2--3
```

Comment: Your answers always teach me something new and interesting about how LaTeX does its magic. Thanks!

Comment: Very instructive. In Norwegian statutes, every clause starts with a §, and when we refer to two or more clauses, we write §§, i.e. see §§ 5, 6 and 8. Is there a simple way to have the macro to check if the next character is a §, and in case not insert the hard space. Actually, a nice feature for your macro would be the possibility to define an exception list, like `xspace` does.

Comment: @Sveinung Kind of off-topic, but do you know if the use of §§ is idiosyncratic to Norwegian conventions? It reminds me of the convention to use pp. instead of p. when citing multiple pages, so now I'm thinking I might be citing multiple sections incorrectly.

Comment: @Dennis: I don’t think it’s just a Norwegian thing. I’ve seen it in quite a few style guides (a mix of American and European ones, iirc).

Comment: @Dennis I have seen it in Danish legal literature (Norway and Denmark was a union for 400 years) and German legal literature. I am not sure, but due to German influence om Danish and Norwegian jurisprudence, I would assume that this notation stems from German tradition, and may be Roman law. But I am not sure.

Answer (score 0):

How about using the `xspace` package:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xspace}

\let\OldS\S
\renewcommand{\S}{\OldS\xspace}

\begin{document}

\S 13

\OldS 13

\S{} 13

\OldS{} 13

\end{document}
```

The advantage is that if you ever want to typeset `\S` before a full stop or comma, `xspace` automatically omits the additional space.

[image: xspace use]

Comment: Ah, great! I was just about to ask why I would use `xspace` instead of Gonzalo's solution of `\renewcommand{\S}{\OldS\ }`, but you beat me to it!

Comment: Won't this suppress the space if the `§` is followed by a punctuation mark?

Comment: Yes, that's the job of `xspace`. Normally if you define a command with a trailing space you get the space also in front of a full stop. Using the `\xspace` command the space is suppressed in front of sentence-closing symbols.