# How to define a macro for a word?

Tags: spacing, macros

I would like to define a macro for a word, i.e.

```
\newcommand{\stack}{{\it StackExchange} Tex}
```

But, I would like to automatically add a final space after that macro, like it is defined as

```
\newcommand{\stack}{{\it StackExchange} Tex }
```

except when the macro is followed by a comma, in order to avoid the situation like:

> *StackExchange* Tex , blablabla...

Any suggestion how to insert a space only if the macro is not followed by a comma/dot character?

Comment: And what about the case when your macro is followed by a full-stop, semicolon etc.

Comment: In general, if it is followed by a space, `\stack blabla` I would like to preserve a space, otherwise substitute the macro without extra characters

Comment: Actually this question was already asked: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31091/2975

Comment: @alessandro308: The old font macros do not stack (you can't have e.g. bold italic), no automatic italic correcteion and they are superseeded by the LaTeX commands. See for further details: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/516/2975

Comment: I like the solution proposed e.g. [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/25825) (which is also somewhere in one of the answers in the question of which this is a duplicate).

Comment: I just added another answer to the question [Space after LaTeX commands](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/472250/118714)