# Macro that ignores the next dot character if its expansion ends with dot character

Tags: punctuation

In short, I want the following ...

```
\def\foo{??????????????}

\def\bar{bar} 
A \foo-foo, a \foo, and a \foo came into a \foo. Says the \foo: Why the \foo?

\def\bar{baz.} 
A \foo-foo, a \foo, and a \foo came into a \foo. Says the \foo: Why the \foo?
```

... to produce the following output:

```
A bar-foo, a bar, and a bar came into a bar. Says the bar: Why the bar?

A baz.-foo, a baz., and a baz. came into a baz. Says the baz.: Why the baz.?
```

That is, I want `\foo` to be equivalent to `\bar` but to prevent printing a double dot `..` if `\bar` ends with `.`and the next character is also `.`.

So far, I manage to do this only with `\bar` doing some bookkeeping (e.g. `\def\bar{bar\endswithpointfalse}` vs.`\def\bar{baz.\endswithpointtrue}` (and `\let\foo\bar`, i.e., no further wrapping needed)  and replacing `\foo.` with `\foo\ifendswithpoint\else.\fi`), but that is tedious in more complicated cases or impossible if `\bar` is third party. As there is apparently no such thing as `\lastchar`, I wonder if any other trick without such bookkeeping is possible?

Comment: Not sure I fully understnad, but it you use `\usepackage{xspace}` and `\def\foo{\bar\xspace}` you should get the desired results.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution that works for your example. It uses `\IfEndWith` from package `xstring` to check if `\bar` ends with `.`, and it uses `\ltx@ifnextchar@nospace` from package `ltxcmds` to check if the next character is a `.`. If both are true, it skips the next character using `\def\ignorenext#1{}`. Note that I had to rename `\foo` to `\foo/` to avoid problems with skipping whitespace as per [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/25825/150114).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{ltxcmds}

\def\ignorenext#1{}

\makeatletter
\def\foo/{\bar\IfEndWith{\bar}{.}{\ltx@ifnextchar@nospace.{\ignorenext}{}}{}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \def\bar{baz}
    A \foo/-foo, a \foo/, and a \foo/ came into a \foo/. Says the \foo/: Why the \foo/?


    \def\bar{baz.}
    A \foo/-foo, a \foo/, and a \foo/ came into a \foo/. Says the \foo/: Why the \foo/?
\end{document}
```

[image: command that skips next . if it also ends with .]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the fact that the period has a very distinctive space factor code.

Here I loaded also `amsthm` because it redefines `\frenchspacing` to keep distinctive space factors for punctuation characters, while not allowing extended spacing.

Possibly gobbling a period is only activated when the space factor code is the same as the period's.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{xspace}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\possibly@gobble@period}{%
  \ifnum\spacefactor=\sfcode`.
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
  {\@ifnextchar{.}{\@gobble}{\xspace}}%
  {\xspace}%
}
\newcommand{\foo}{\baz\possibly@gobble@period}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\baz}{baz}

\begin{document}

A \foo-foo, a \foo, and a \foo came into a \foo. Says the \foo: Why the \foo?

\renewcommand{\baz}{baz.}

A \foo-foo, a \foo, and a \foo came into a \foo. Says the \foo: Why the \foo?

\frenchspacing

A \foo-foo, a \foo, and a \foo came into a \foo. Says the \foo: Why the \foo?

\end{document}
```

[image]