# What do newcommand, renewcommand, and providecommand do, and how do they differ?

Tags: macros

What do newcommand, renewcommand, and providecommand do, and how do they differ?

I think `\newcommand` overwrites any previously existing command, while `\providecommand` creates the command only if it does not already exists.  Does `\renewcommand` only work on already extant commands?

Answer (score 229, accepted):

No, it is not correct.

`\newcommand` defines a new command, and makes an error if it is already defined.

`\renewcommand` redefines a predefined command, and makes an error if it is not yet defined.

`\providecommand` defines a new command if it isn't already defined.

If you want to define a command whether it is new or predefined, you can use `\def` or

```
\providecommand\foo{}
\renewcommand\foo{...}
```

Comment: I never knew what to do with `\providecommand` or how to do this unconditional definition in LaTeX-style code.  Thanks!

Comment: For some reason there appears to be missing a "define a macro even if it's already defined". Of course there is the plain old `\def`, but this sacrifices the ease of use of the LaTeX macros. The easiest way to emulate this is to `\let\foo\outer\renewcommand\foo{stuff}`. (I chose `\outer` because it's pretty likely to produce errors if used incorrectly). The best solution would of course be to make a `\defcommand` that always overwrote its argument regardless, but it would have to have a starred version like `\newcommand` and friends which complicates matters a bit...

Comment: I guess this would work: `\makeatletter\def\defcommand{\@ifstar\defcommand@S\defcommand@N} \def\defcommand@S#1{\let#1\outer\renewcommand*#1} \def\defcommand@N#1{\let#1\outer\renewcommand#1} \makeatother`. (God I hate that we can't have linebreaks in comments...)

Answer (score 75):

They have all in common, that they define a new command, but the precondition and behavior differs a bit:

- `\renewcommand` works only if the command is already defined: it's a redefinition
- `\newcommand` doesn't work if the command is already defined: so it's a completely new definition
- `\providecommand` works like `\newcommand`, but if the command is already defined, the (re)definition is ignored

`\renewcommand` and `\newcommand` would throw an error, if the condition is not fulfilled, to ensure clean programming, so you don't accidentally overwrite existing commands or try to redefine one which doesn't exist.

`\providecommand` may be helpful, if the same code would be used in several documents. If you would use it, you should be aware that it might have no effect. But using it you can avoid compile time errors.

For all commands exists a starred version. To see the difference, have a look at:

- [What's the difference between \newcommand and \newcommand*?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1050/whats-the-difference-between-newcommand-and-newcommand)

If you really don't want error checking, you could use `\def`, see:

- [What is the difference between \def and \newcommand?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/655/what-is-the-difference-between-def-and-newcommand)

Answer (score 29):

The idea is to prevent an *accidental* overwriting of commands by a not so knowledgeable user.

1. `\newcommand` defines a new command and gives an error if the command already exists.  It does *not* overwrite an existing command.
2. `\renewcommand` overwrites an existing command and gives an error if the command does *not* already exist.
3. `\providecommand` defines a new command if the command with this name does not exist, or does nothing if it exists.

Exercise: use `\providecommand` and `\renewcommand` to define a command which may either exist or not.

Comment: Leo Liu's answer already contains the solution to your exercise.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina We wrote our texts simulatenously :)