# define new command: \renewcommand{\longto}{\longrightarrow}

Tags: macros

I define this new command:

```
\documentclass[8pt,a4paper]{article}
\newcounter{conto}
\setcounter{conto}{\time}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{ dsfont }
\usepackage[mathscr]{euscript}
\renewcommand{\longto}{\longrightarrow}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=1cm,bottom=2cm,left=3cm,right=3cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\begin{flushleft}
\( a \longto +\infty \)
\end{flushleft}
\end{document}
```

but the command `\renewcommand{\longto}{\longrightarrow}` doesn't work!!

Comment: What do you mean by «Doesn't work»? I do get the arrow. **EDIT:** Ah, you edited. `renewcommand` is used to change the definition of a command, as the log says `Error: \longto undefined.`, you only need to substitute `\renewcommand` with `\newcommand`.

Comment: `\longto` is not defined, so you have to `\newcommand{\longto}{\longrightarrow}`

Comment: @karlkoeller You should post your comment as an answer

Comment: @Soviet Read this post: [What do newcommand, renewcommand, and providecommand do, and how do they differ?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36175/10898)

Comment: `\let\longto\longrightarrow`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The command `\longto` is not defined, so you can not "renew" its meaning through `\renewcommand`, which can only be used to redefine existing commands.

To define a new command, as in your case, you have to use `\newcommand`, specifically:

```
\newcommand{\longto}{\longrightarrow}
```

See this post for more info: [What do newcommand, renewcommand, and providecommand do, and how do they differ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36175/10898)

Answer (score 5):

If you want to be on the save side then use:

```
\providecommand\longto{}% does nothing, if already defined
\renewcommand\longto{\longrightarrow}% works now
```

or if you want the short way:

```
\let\longto\longrightarrow
```

Comment: I can't recommend this. A package might define `\longto` and use it in some of its constructions; the macro would be redefined without any warning.

Comment: sure, but a `\@ifdefinable` is overkill in this _special_ case!

Comment: That's what `\newcommand` is for; why looking for complications?

Comment: It looks like that you never wrote a package ...

Comment: This is *for a document level definition*, not for a package. The user level command for this *is* `\newcommand` that will inform the user in case the macro already has a definition; in this case suitable action can be taken. Try imagining what would happen if somebody follows your advice with `\box` instead of `\longto`. Your answer should start with “If you want to be on the unsafe side…”.

Comment: That is your point of view! And there is another one: I want definitively define _my_ command called `\box`. Then I'll go my way.