# How to define _or_ redefine a command (mixing \providecommand + \renewcommand)?

Tags: macros

In some situations I wish there was a way to define a command `\tmp` so that

- if `\tmp` does not exist: Defined `\tmp`
- if `\tmp` does exits: Redefine `\tmp`

My current approach is simply to use either `\newcommand` or `\renewcommand`. However, this means that I often have to change from one version to the other if I reorder my documents and sometimes limits the overall reusability of my code.

In [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36175/30658) I learned about `\providecommand`, which almost solves my problem: It can be used irrespective of whether `\tmp` is defined, but it only defines on the first occurrence and does not overwrite. This lead me to the naive attempt:

```
\newcommand{\overwritecommand}[2]{
  \providecommand{#1}{#2}
  \renewcommand{#1}{#2}
}
```

However, this approach is obviously not general enough:

```
% it works for
\overwritecommand{\tmp}{test}

% but not for commands with arguments like
\overwritecommand{\tmp}[1]{test: #1} 
% Error: You can't use `macro parameter character #' in horizontal mode.
```

Is there any other way to achive the *define or overwrite* behavior?

Comment: Do you mean `\def`?

Comment: @jon: Does `\def` somehow allow to use optional arguments as well?

Comment: `\newcommand{\declarecommand}[1]{\providecommand{#1}{}\renewcommand{#1}}` But, for your own safety, ***don't*** use it! Something like `\declarecommand{\box}[1]{\fbox{#1}` would be funnily disastrous.

Comment: It can be used that way.  The package `xparse` has `\DeclareDocumentCommand`, which is much easier to use; there's also various `\def`-related commands in the package `etoolbox`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, there is a method:

```
\newcommand{\declarecommand}[1]{\providecommand{#1}{}\renewcommand{#1}}
```

Why does it work? Because TeX uses macro expansion and it's irrelevant what `\providecommand` defines `#1` to be, if `#1` wasn't defined, because you redefine it immediately.

Now that you know how to do it, try

```
\declarecommand{\box}[1]{\fbox{#1}}
```

and enjoy the wreck!

There *is* a reason why LaTeX doesn't provide a `\declarecommand` function: you ***MUST*** be aware whether you are redefining an existent command.

If you want to allow the optional `*`, then

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand\declarecommand{\@star@or@long\@declarecommand}
\newcommand\@declarecommand[1]{%
  \provide@command{#1}{}%
  \renew@command{#1}%
}
\makeatother
```

will do.

Comment: Drat: I was just posting more or less the same thing but was held up thinking about the optional star and whether to handle it!

Comment: @JosephWright It would be easy to comply with the optional `*`, but the idea is wrong to begin with!

Comment: Thanks. Took me a moment to see how it works. Nice trick!

Comment: this looks evil.  hope i never have to debug a journal submission that uses it.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I hope I made clear *why* one shouldn't use it. There are several ways to shoot one's own foot, this one is quite funny.

Comment: oh, yes, quite clear enough.  but i've (unfortunately) encountered a number of authors who would only take this as a challenge.  tar and feathers is much too mild a punishment ...

Answer (score 3):

I understand that you need `\def` but with parameters like `\newcommand`. It is possible to define our own`\newcommand` which ignores if the defined control sequence has a meaning. For example we can use the code from [this page](http://petr.olsak.net/opmac-tricks-e.html#newcommand):

```
\def\newcommand#1{\isnextchar[{\newcommandA#1}{\newcommandA#1[0]}}
\def\newcommandA#1[#2]{\edef\tmpp{\ifcase#2%
   \or1\or12\or123\or1234\or12345\or123456\or1234567\or12345678\or123456789\fi}%
   \edef\tmpp{\expandafter\addhashs\tmpp.}%
   \isnextchar[{\newcommandB#1}{\long\expandafter\def\expandafter#1\tmpp}%
}
\def\newcommandB#1[#2]{%
   \def#1{\isnextchar[{\runcommand#1}{\runcommand#1[#2]}}%
   \long\expandafter\def\csname\string#1X\expandafter\endcsname\tmpp
}
\def\addhashs#1{\ifx.#1\else #####1\expandafter\addhashs\fi}
\long\def\runcommand#1[#2]{\csname\string#1X\endcsname{#2}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the classic examples have already been shown, I'll just add the `xparse` way, which is quite user-friendly:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\DeclareDocumentCommand{\foo}{m}
 {Foo: #1}
\begin{document}

\foo{bar}

\DeclareDocumentCommand{\foo}{om}
 {\IfNoValueTF{#1}%
   {Bar: no optional, just #2}%
   {Bar: optional = #1, plus #2}%
 }%

\foo{Baz}

\foo[Bar]{Baz}

\end{document}
```