# How to define *and* redefine in class file?

Tags: macros, renewcommand

I'm creating a resume and have create my own custom resume class (doesn't everybody?). I have multiple positions that I want to typeset so I have something like this:

```latex
\documentclass{mcv}

\begin{document}

\positiontitle{Manager}
\begin{position}
...
\end{position}

\positiontitle{Pee-on}
\begin{position}
...
\end{position}

\end{document}
```

This works well until I add the second position title (i.e., `Pee-on`). Then I get an error like `LaTeX Error: Command \@positiontitle already defined`. Of course it is I defined it earlier, but now I need *re*-define it and I'm not sure how to do this.

Using [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/228865/6324) I found some help so I tried to implement my command in this way:

```tex
\newcommand{\positiontitle}{\newcommand\@positiontitle{#1}}
\newcommand{\@positiontitle}[1]{%
   \provide@command{#1}{}%
   \renew@command{#1}%
}
```

Unfortunately, that didn't do the trick and I'm still getting the same "already defined" error. I must be doing something wrong, but I don't know what it is.

Comment: Code we can't compile isn't of much use for testing, and it's pretty unclear what you're trying to do. Shouldn't `\positiontitle` be the one with the argument (and why would the initial definition of `\@positiontitle` have one)? Does changing the first command to `\newcommand{\positiontitle}[1]{\renewcommand\@positiontitle{#1}}` and the second to something like `\newcommand{\@positiontitle}{Default Position}` solve your problem? If not, explain further what the use of these commands is supposed to be.

Comment: Thank you @frabjous for interpreting my gibberish. I apologize it wasn't more clear. The problem was that I file to have `renewcommand` as you suggested.

Comment: If you don't need an error-message in case `\@positiontitle` is not already defined, then use `\def` instead of `\renewcommand`.