# bibliography with APA-like sorting, volume, issue, doi, url: which bibliography style and options?

Tags: bibtex, apa-style, sorting, doi, url

I have one question: which bibliography style should one use to get all references sorted APA-like, and with volume, issue, and doi (or URL, where a DOI does not exist; or nothing, where both DOI and URL do not exist). I tried the apalike style, and I do get the APA-like sorting, volume, and issue, but not the DOI nor URL. If I use plainnat, I get volume, issue, and DOI/ URL (with additional use of the DOI package), and a reasonable alphabetical sorting, but not strictly APA-like. I would be grateful if anyone could help with any suggestions on how to get APA-like sorting and all aforementioned bibtex (I use bibtex) fields?

Answer (score 1):

problem solved through the `apacite` package with the option `[natbibapa]` (to keep my previous `\citep` and `\citet` commands valid) and with the option to use the prefix https://doi.org/ according to latest APA guidelines, as in this example: [using APA6 style with current DOI specifications](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/368802/using-apa6-style-with-current-doi-specifications?rq=1)