# Could somebody please explain why definition throws an error?

Tags: errors

The following definition of \sp throws a "Missing $" error, I cant see any possible reason for this!    Could somebody please explain?

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\providecommand{\sp}[1][10]{\par \vspace{#1 pt} \noindent\ignorespaces}
\begin{document}
line
\sp
line
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\documentclass{amsart}` twice??

Comment: Because `\sp` is the superscript operator and `\providecommand` will not override the original definition.

Comment: Exactly! you must change the command's name `\sp` for other. (`\sp` already exists)

Comment: While `\providecommand` has its uses, I'd discourage using it for personal commands: use `\newcommand`, which would warn you in case you're trying to define an existing command.

Comment: Your question is most likely solved by reading [What do `\newcommand`, `\renewcommand`, and `\providecommand` do, and how do they differ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36175/5764)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to accept the answer in a comment, but if I knew I would accept @HenriMenke's comment, which is clearly the best practice.     On the other hand, while I should never have used `\sp` in the first place, I've been using it for years and it's hard to change.   The following *does* work, i.e., overrides the default definition of `\sp`

```
\let\sp\undefined
\newcommand{\sp}[1][10]{\par\vspace{#1pt}\noindent\ignorespaces}
```

bad practice as it is.