# Determine within LaTeX how many times latexmk have run

Tags: pdftex, knitr, latexmk

### Backround

So I've gathered that latexmk runs pdflatex until "all files are up to date".

### Problem and motivation

Say that I have some dynamic content that should only be run once. By dynamic I mean a content that changes every time you run it.

In principle: assume you could have a command `\randomNumber` which change every time it is run, giving you a random number, and thus causes latexmk to run forever.

A real world example would be compiling `Rnw`-files that have randomness in them.

```
\immediate\write18{compileMyKnitr}\input{myRnw.tex}
```

### Question

Is there

1. A latex command that will tell me how many runs latexmk have done

and/or

2. Some fancy logic that can be done with e.g. the .aux file to determine whether this is the first run or not?

Ideally `\ifFirstRun{\doSomething}` or `\LatexmkRunOnce{\doSomething}`

Comment: a smilar question was answered here. a) you can use the aux file to save and restore number of runs b) i think your 2 nd point is good in this situation.

Comment: You can use `\IfFileExists{\jobname.aux}{yes}{no}` in the preamble as the aux file is generated on the first run, at `\begin{document}` so by definition it's not there on teh first run in the preamble

Comment: @DavidCarlisle no (yes-no) in preamble :-)

Comment: Was actually considering writing `Missing \begin{document}`, but refrained, haha.

Comment: @touhami it was  a meta comment yes== yes code :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two parts to a solution.

First is to make a .tex file that detects whether it's being compiled on the first run or not:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\AtEndDocument{\write\@auxout{\gdef\string\notfirstrun{}}}
\newcommand{\iffirstrun}{%
    \@ifundefined{notfirstrun}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
foo
\iffirstrun{yes}{no}
\end{document}
```

(Note that the syntax for the use of `\iffirstrun` is different from that for standard `\iff...` constructs.  That could be fixed, of course.)

This solution puts a line `\gdef\notfirstrun{}` in the .aux file, to flag that the next run is not the first.

However, with only that part of the solution, when `latexmk` is again invoked after a change in source file(s), the first actual run will not be treated as a first run by the document. This is normally not desired. One could avoid this by deleting the .aux file, which may result in a lot of extra processing (and is easy to forget). This problem is solved by the following code in a `latexmkrc` file:

```
$latex = 'internal my_latex latex %O %S';
$lualatex = 'internal my_latex lualatex %O %S';
$pdflatex = 'internal my_latex pdflatex %O %S';
$xelatex = 'internal my_latex xelatex -no-pdf %O %S';
sub my_latex {
   if ( ( -e $aux_main ) && ($pass{$rule} == 1) ) {
      print "========Remove any 'notfirstline' line from aux file\n";
      my $aux_bak = "$aux_main.bak";
      rename $aux_main, $aux_bak;
      my $auxold = new FileHandle;
      my $auxnew = new FileHandle;
      open $auxold, "<$aux_bak";
      open $auxnew, ">$aux_main";
      while (<$auxold>) {
         if ( ! /^\\gdef \\notfirstrun\{\}$/ ) { print $auxnew $_; }
      }
      close $auxold;
      close $auxnew;
  }
  return system( @_ );
}
```

It uses a couple of internal variables of `latexmk`: `$aux_main` and `$pass{$rule}`.

Comment: very nice work :-)

Answer (score 4):

Here is a solution. Deleting the `.aux` means restart the counter, (even if no counter is used here).

**1)**

```
\documentclass{article}

\providecommand\runsnumber{1}
\makeatletter
\AtEndDocument{%
    \write\@auxout{%
        \xdef\string\runsnumber{\the\numexpr\runsnumber+1\relax}}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
foo

\runsnumber
\end{document}
```

**2)**

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\AtEndDocument{\write\@auxout{\gdef\string\notfirstrun{}}}
\newcommand{\iffirstrun}{%
    \@ifundefined{notfirstrun}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
foo
\iffirstrun{yes}{no}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Awesome! I will just take your word for it that it works, since I don't have the files here to test it. One question though: Why `\providecommand`?

Comment: `\providecommand` defines the command only in first run since it is not defined yet. [see here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36175/what-do-newcommand-renewcommand-and-providecommand-do-and-how-do-they-differ)

Comment: One complication: Suppose you have already compiled the document so that the .aux file exists, you change a source file, and then compile the document again by `latexmk`. Because of the line in the .aux file defining `\notfirstrun`, the first compilation will be treated as a not-first run by the document. To overcome this, one can delete the .aux file first, as the answer points out.  But it would also be possible to arrange for `latexmk` to fix the .aux file on the first run.  I could provide suitable definition to put in a latexmkrc file.

Comment: @JohnCollins good point

Comment: @AndreasStorvikStrauman this is just to see the new comment

Comment: @JohnCollins If you have a suitable definition that would be great!!

Comment: @AndreasStorvikStrauman I've added a suitable definition.

Comment: @JohnCollins it's better if you write a new answer.

Comment: @touhami Will do.  Since your answer gave a correct solution and had already been accepted, it seemed better simply to improve it.

Comment: Wow! You guys are amazing! Answers like these are the ones that have inspired me to be active on this site. Thank you @JohnCollins and @touhami!

Comment: @AndreasStorvikStrauman your welcome :-)

Comment: @touhami The first example will not work with latexmk because `\runsnumber` keep changing every run, and thus latexmk will never be satisified!

Comment: you can start by deleting the .aux or no?

Comment: According to lthooks documentation (page 21), one should replace in that case `\AtEndDocument` by `\AddToHook{enddocument/afterlastpage}`.