# What is this \newcommand argument?

Tags: macros, arguments

```
\newcommand*{\name}[1][C]{%
```

I have come very familiar with `\newcommand` however, I came across this line of code and i do not know what the `[C]` is for.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! This means in this case that `\name` has one optional argument whose default value is `C`.

Comment: https://latexref.xyz/_005cnewcommand-_0026-_005crenewcommand.html#g_t_005cnewcommand-_0026-_005crenewcommand

Comment: @HenriMenke Is there a more modern link in which things like `\it` do not get advertized?

Comment: @marmot Well, `\it` etc. are commands provided by the standard LaTeX classes, so naturally they would be listed in a reference manual.  However, you can contribute and remove them https://latexref.xyz/dev/writing.html

Comment: @HenriMenke Please don't get me wrong, this was not meant to criticize you. I have just seen so many cases in which users, especially new users, got interesting comments when they were using `\it` and so on. Therefore I am really wondering if there are sources of the same information which a free of such relics.

Answer (score 4):

LaTeX's `\newcommand` has the following syntax:

> ```
> \newcommand *{<\FOO>}[<i>]{<TEXT>}
> ```
>
> User command to define `\FOO` to be a macro with `i` arguments (`i` = 0 if missing)
>   having the definition `<TEXT>`. Produces an error if `\FOO` already defined.
>   Normally the command is defined to be `\long` (*i.e.* it may take multiple paragraphs in its argument). In the star-form, the command is not defined as `\long`
>   and a blank line in any argument to the command would generate an error.

If you define a command with at least one argument (`i` > 0), you can specify an additional (optional) argument before the definition `<TEXT>`. This optional argument will be used as the "default" value for a *first* optional argument to `\FOO`.

So, as an example, consider

```
\newcommand{\FOO}[2]{<TEXT>}
```

This command has two mandatory arguments and is therefore used as `\FOO{<one>}{<two>}`. However,

```
\newcommand{\FOO}[2][X]{<TEXT>}
```

takes two (`2`) arguments, the first of which is optional and has a default of `X` (if not supplied). You can use it as `\FOO{<one>}` (which is equivalent to `\FOO[X]{<one>}`) or `\FOO[<one>]{<two>}`. Similarly,

```
\newcommand{\FOO}[1][X]{<TEXT>}
```

takes a single (`1`) optional argument that has a default value of `X` (if not supplied) and can be used as `\FOO` (which is equivalent to `\FOO[X]`) or `\FOO[<one>]`.

---

In your particular case,

```
\newcommand*{\name}[1][C]{<TEXT>}
```

defines `\name` to (be non-`\long`; that is, `<TEXT>` cannot have blank lines and) take a single (`1`) optional argument that defaults to `C` if not supplied. You can use it as `\name` (which is equivalent to `\name[C]`) or `\name[<one>]`.

Reference:

- [LaTeX2e sources](https://www.tug.org/texlive/Contents/live/texmf-dist/doc/latex/base/source2e.pdf)
- [What do `\newcommand`, `\renewcommand`, and `\providecommand` do, and how do they differ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36175/5764)
- [What is the difference between `\def` and `\newcommand`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/655/5764)