# Beamer dagger footnote

Tags: beamer

I have been googling for ages.

I want to add a double-dagger footnote to the title in my beamer presentation.

I am using `\thanks` for the footnote as this seems to work.  But I cannot change to a dagger.  All the answers I have found apply to articles not beamer presentations.

This is what I have got so far...  I have include all the preamble in case it makes a difference (I am new to latex and it seems too...).

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=1610]{beamer}

\usetheme{Szeged}        % {Szeged}   {Dresden}
\usecolortheme{beaver}   % {beaver}   {spruce}
\usefonttheme{serif}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[square]
\usepackage{framed,color}
\definecolor{shadecolor}{rgb}{1,0.4,0.4}

\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{caption}

\newcommand{\source}[1]{\caption*{Source: {#1}} }
\def\fnsymbol#1{\expandafter\@fnsymbol\csname c@#1\endcsname}

\title{My Title\thanks{My footnote.}}
\institute{\small My Organisation}
\date{\scriptsize Very very soon}
\author{Me}


\begin{document}

%%  Title slide

\begin{frame}
    \titlepage
\end{frame}
```

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the following suits your needs:

[image]

I've used `\renewcommand*{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}` in order to switch from numbered footnotes to symbols. Instead of `\thanks`, I have used `\footnote[3]{...}` since double dagger is the third symbol in the list. In order to avoid having the footnote symbol ext to the title in  the footline, I have used the optional argument of the `\title` command.

Additionally, I have used `\setbeamerfont{...}{size=\...}` in order to change the font size of `institute`  and `date` rather than adding the font sized directly into the `\institute` and `\date` commands.

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=1610]{beamer}

\usetheme{Szeged}
\usecolortheme{beaver}  
\usefonttheme{serif}

\usepackage{fourier}

\renewcommand*{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}

\setbeamerfont{institute}{size=\small}
\setbeamerfont{date}{size=\scriptsize}


\title[My title]{My Title\footnote[3]{My footnote.}}
\institute{My Organisation}
\date{Very very soon}
\author{Me}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \titlepage
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is perfect.  Thanks so much!!!  And I appreciate the other changes you made to my preamble - it is a great way to learn.  I'm find Latex heavy going at the moment...

Comment: What is the difference between renewcommand and newcommand?

Comment: @brb: `\newcommand` can be used to create a new command while `\renewcommand` can be used to change an already existing command. For more information, you might want to have a look at [What do newcommand, renewcommand, and providecommand do, and how do they differ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36175/134144)

Comment: Thank you for the link.  I will read with interest.