# Why does \renewcommand error if the command does not exist?

Tags: macros

I use the same preamble in several projects. The set of already-defined commands is different between the environments. In one project, `\eps` is already defined, whereas in another it is not. I wish to define `\eps` as `\varepsilon`.

The [Latex2e unofficial reference manual](https://web.archive.org/web/20200208233950/http://joshua.smcvt.edu/latex2e/_005cnewcommand-_0026-_005crenewcommand.html) says:

> If you try to define a command and the name has already been used then you get something like `<error>`. If you try to redefine a command and the name has not yet been used then you get something like `<different error>`.

Therefore, neither can be used in my situation. I can get around the issue like this:

```
\ifdefined\eps
    \renewcommand{\eps}{\varepsilon}
\else
    \newcommand{\eps}{\varepsilon}
\fi
```

but this is quite clunky. I don't understand why `\renewcommand` should complain if the command does not already exist. Either way, we are supplying our desired definition of the command.

Comment: To avoid checks on pre-definition, you could use `\def\eps{\varepsilon}`.  This will work whether `\eps` is predefined or not.

Comment: You may use `\providecommand` as explained [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36175/what-do-newcommand-renewcommand-and-providecommand-do-and-how-do-they-differ).
If `cmd` is not defined, `providecommand` defines it.

Answer (score 14):

"Why" questions are hard to answer. In this case the answer is "Because Leslie Lamport chose this definition in the early 1980s".

However if `\renewcommand` acted as you suggest then it would be equivalent to `\newcommand` with no check on the command being defined at all. This would negate much of the reason for having `\newcommand` which is to protect the user from accidentally redefining latex internals and breaking the system.

As Steven comments under your question, the behaviour would then be like the TeX primitive `\def` which always defines (or redefines) the supplied command. Even now you often see users using `\def` in latex documents and overwriting internal commands.

The idea is that you use `\newcommand` and get warned if something is about to go wrong, and then only if you know that it is Ok to do so, use `\renewcommand` for redefinitions.

You could define your command more simply as

```
  \def\zzcommand#1{\let#1\undefined\newcommand#1}
```

which undefines the command first so that `\newcommand` always succeeds, but then try

```
\zzcommand\box{\fbox{X}}
```

for example.

Answer (score 6):

If in one of the environments `\eps` has already been defined to give one of the forms of epsilon, you just do

```
\providecommand{\eps}{\varepsilon}
\renewcommand{\epsilon}{\varepsilon}
```

and usage of `\eps` will produce `\varepsilon` in both environments.

If `\eps` is defined to do something else, then you're doomed.

---

Why does `\renewcommand` balk if fed with an undefined command? Because `\renewcommand` should be used with care and knowing what one is doing.

Comment: "If \eps is defined to do something else, then you're doomed." – why? Won't this code just redefine it as `\varepsilon`?

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann Yes, but the people using it with another meaning would be appalled.

Answer (score 2):

This is a simple example from Leo Liu's answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36175/what-do-newcommand-renewcommand-and-providecommand-do-and-how-do-they-differ).

`\providecommand` only redefines the command `\foo` if this command is not previously defined.

If `\newcommand` defines `\foo`, then `\providecommand` will be silented.

With `\providecommand`, there will always exist a `\foo` to become `meh` through `\renewcommand`.

I'm not sure if this is the most elegant answer, but it is very simple and clear.

```
\documentclass{article}
% (un)comment to change \providecommand behavior
\newcommand{\foo}{foo}
% if {\foo} not defined, then {\foo} is ``bla''
\providecommand{\foo}{bla}
% {\foo} will always become ``meh''
\renewcommand{\foo}{meh}
\begin{document}
{\foo}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Unless I misunderstand, `\providecommand` is not equivalent to the `\if` statement in my question. If `\eps` is already defined, I want to *change* it, not use the current definition.

Comment: Oh nevermind, I get it now. The *combination* of the empty `\providecommand` followed by the `\renewcommand` is the suggested idiom, correct?

Comment: @japreiss, that's correctly. Indeed, i almost gave you this exactly wrong answer by forgetting the `renewcommand` line. This syntax keeps your commands at the LaTeX level, without digging further into the TeX level.