# How to align a vertical tree to the upper-left corner?

Tags: tikz-pgf, trees, tikz-trees

How do I align vertical trees to to the top?

This is my current tree:       I want to get this tree:
[image]
                 [image]
*^ That's a part of my current tree*

I'm trying to create a graph which illustrates a path algorithm of `O(N!)`. For readability, I only show descendants for the top node, all of the lower nodes should be postfixed by a fork- / rake-like object.

I'd appreciate an answer which shows the correct solution, plus an explanation of the used code.

My relevant code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree,tikz-qtree-compat}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{grow'=right,level distance=50pt}
\tikzset{execute at begin node=\strut}
\tikzset{every tree node/.style={align=left,anchor=base west}}
\Tree [.\node(root){E};
           [.A \node(x){R};
               [.D ]
               [.U ]
               [.T ]
           ]
           [.R ]
           [.D ]
           [.U ]
           [.T ]
      ]
      [.R ]
      [.D ]
      [.U ]
      [.T ]
]
\draw[->](x)..controls +(north west:1.5) .. (root);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I get centered dots after `R` if I write `[ .R{\,$\cdots$} ]` in the descendents of `E`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perhaps a tree is not the right way to go for what you want to achieve. This example uses a matrix to place the nodes in the desired way.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth]
    \matrix[matrix of nodes,column sep=2em,row sep=1em] (tree) {
      E & A & R & D & U & T \\
        & R & D & U & T &   \\
        & D & U & T &   &   \\
        & U & T &   &   &   \\
        & T &   &   &   &   \\
    };
    \foreach \n in {1,2,3,4,5} {\path (tree-1-1) edge (tree-\n-2);};
    \foreach \n in {1,2,3,4} {\path (tree-1-2) edge (tree-\n-3);};
    \foreach \n in {1,2,3} {\path (tree-1-3) edge (tree-\n-4);};
    \foreach \n in {1,2} {\path (tree-1-4) edge (tree-\n-5);};
    \path (tree-1-5) edge (tree-1-6);
    \path (tree-1-6) edge[->,bend right=15] (tree-1-1);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The syntax is not as comfortable as typing a tree, but the result is what you want.

---

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How can I add a fork after the other letters (looks like a `<-`, with the hyphen slightly shifted to the left`)?

Comment: You could construct the fork with `\newcommand*\myfork{\ensuremath{{-\mkern-20mu <}}}` and then add that to the relevant nodes.  To keep the alignment, set  `text width=1em` in the `\matrix` options.

Comment: @AlanMunn Thanks! What's the difference between `\newcommand*` and `\newcommand`? Also, how can I dynamically insert the fork, rather than typing `\myfork`several times?

Comment: @RobW The `*` prevents the command from containing `\par`. See [What's the difference between \newcommand and \newcommand*?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1050/2693) for the complete story.  As for dynamically inserting the fork, I don't see a simple way since the nodes in the matrix aren't themselves dynamically created.  You could define a command to insert an end node like the following: `\newcommand*\endnode[1]{#1\myfork}` and then use `\endnode{R}` etc. to insert the nodes you want to have the fork.  That's semantically clearer, but doesn't save you much typing.

Comment: I ended up using the fork as suggested by @AlanMunn. Instead of manually typing it all over again, I used two RegExes to pad the `&` and add the `\fork`. Thanks for your help!