# Faster way of writing \mathbf

Tags: math-mode, bold

Is there a quicker way of doing **boldface** in math mode instead of typing out `\mathbf{}` each time?  (It gets cumbersome when you denote simple vectors with **boldface**...)

Comment: Can't you just define your own command for the vectors?  How are you writing it now?

Comment: Every time I have a vector, I write `$\mathbf{x}$`.

Comment: I'd rather use `\bm` from the `bm` package, does not get much fater than that, and then `$\bm{v}=(v_1,v_2,\dots,v_n)$` does not look odd any more (seems to to me to use upright bold instead of italic bold)

Comment: your input would be more scrutable to someone else if you define a shorthand that makes obvious the vector nature of the symbols, rather than just the fact that they're boldface.

Comment: For vectors, I would suggest using `\vec{}`, and redefining `\vec{}` appropriately. If you want vectors to be bold, you can use `\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}%`. If you want vectors indicated by arrows, just comment out that out.

Comment: Also, `\mathbf{}` doesn't work in `align` statements across the alignment symbol.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

There's a really cheesy way of saving keystrokes that is no longer than Todd's answer but just as comprehensive as Yiannis's:

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\*#1{\mathbf{#1}}

\def\ab{ab}
\begin{document}
 $\*v, \*w, \*\ab, \*\Gamma$.
\end{document}
```

Explanation: a control sequence whose name is a non-letter doesn't require either spaces or braces after it (unless of course you want it to act on multiple tokens, like plain `ab`; a macro such as my `\ab` will work just fine, though).

Comment: Ooh. That is a really cool trick.

Comment: This is the best solution so far.

Comment: Very elegant and very easy to use solution. That's great !

Comment: One should remember, though, that this will remove the original definition of `\*`.

Comment: @egreg true. Though I've never used that, to the point that I didn't know there was one.

Comment: @RyanReich You'd have discovered it if you had used `\newcommand` (which is one of the main reasons for the command to exist).

Comment: @egreg Good point. I was a bit of a hotshot when I wrote this answer.

Answer (score 15):

Just to expand on Todd Lehman's answer, you can save a bit of typing in the definitions, by automating the creation of the commands:

The LaTeX kernel has a looping construct named `\@tfor` that enables parsing a list of characters. We leverage this to define commands of the form `\Va..\Vz` and `\VA..\VZ` automatically using `\csname..\endcsname`.

```
\@tfor\next:=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ\do{%
  \def\command@factory#1{%
    \expandafter\def\csname V#1\endcsname{#1}
  }
 \expandafter\command@factory\next
}
```

The full MWE is shown below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\@tfor\next:=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ\do{%
  \def\command@factory#1{%
    \expandafter\def\csname V#1\endcsname{#1}
  }
 \expandafter\command@factory\next
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\[ a \cdot (\Vv \otimes \Vw) = (a \cdot \Vv) \otimes \Vw = \Vv \otimes (a \cdot \Vw) \]
\end{document}
```

To have bold greek, we can use a similar technique. This time we will put all the greek letters in a comma delimited list, like:

```
 alpha,beta,gamma,zeta...Alpha...Zeta
```

we can then iterate over it, this time using a `@for` loop, here is the amended minimal.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathpazo}

\makeatletter
\@tfor\next:=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ\do{%
  \def\command@factory#1{%
    \expandafter\def\csname V#1\endcsname{\mathbb{#1}}
  }
 \expandafter\command@factory\next
}
\begin{document}
\[ a \cdot (\Vv \otimes \Vw) = (a \cdot \Vv) \otimes \Vw = \Vv \otimes (a \cdot \Vw) \]

\def\greekvectors#1{%
 \@for\next:=#1\do{%
    \def\X##1;{%
     \expandafter\def\csname V##1\endcsname{\boldsymbol{\csname##1\endcsname}}
     }
   \expandafter\X\next;
  }
}

\greekvectors{alpha,beta,iota,gamma,lambda,nu,eta,Gamma,varsigma}

 $\VGamma\Viota\Valpha\Vnu\Vnu\Veta\Vvarsigma$
\end{document}
```

Will output

[image]

Comment: Nice! And how about the Greek letters?

Comment: @ToddLehman I would do them as `\Valpha`, `\Vbeta` etc., by looping through a comma delimited list. Will add it to the MWE.

Comment: `\command@factory`... that's epic!

Comment: Shouldn't the `\def`s be outside of the loops?

Comment: @AndreyVihrov Probably better to optimize. This way saved  quite a few `\expandafter`s.

Answer (score 14):

What you want is not necessarily a faster way to write `\mathbf{v}`, but a faster way to obtain the vector **v**, yes?

In this case, I would define a set of very short letter-specific macros, one for each vector variable. For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\Vu}{\mathbf{u}}
\newcommand{\Vv}{\mathbf{v}}
\newcommand{\Vw}{\mathbf{w}}
\newcommand{\Vx}{\mathbf{x}}
\newcommand{\Vy}{\mathbf{y}}
\newcommand{\Vz}{\mathbf{z}}
\begin{document}
\[ \|\Vx\| = \sqrt{\Vx_1^2 + \cdots + \Vx_n^2} \]
\[ a(\Vu+\Vv) = a\Vu + a\Vv \]
\[ a_1\Vv_{i_1} + a_2\Vv_{i_2} + \cdots + a_n\Vv_{i_n} = 0 \]
\[ a \cdot (\Vv \otimes \Vw) = (a \cdot \Vv) \otimes \Vw = \Vv \otimes (a \cdot \Vw) \]
\end{document}
```

[image: example]

Comment: Most of the times this is perhaps the easiest and most convenient solution. Also reminds you that you are dealing with some mathematical object (i.e. vector "b"); rather than some formatting issue.

Answer (score 12):

You can define a `\newcommand*{\V}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}`, then you can just write `\V{x}`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand*{\V}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}%
\begin{document}
    $\mathbf{x} \V{x}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: What is the difference between `\newcommand` and `\newcommand*`?  Also, are there any differences between this solution and @alexis's solution?

Comment: For the first question see [What's the difference between \newcommand and \newcommand*?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1050/whats-the-difference-between-newcommand-and-newcommand). For the second question, this solution requires that you be in math mode and will result in an error if you are not, where as @alexis's solution will not result in an error if used outside of math mode. For a discussion on this see [When not to use \ensuremath for math macro?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34830/when-not-to-use-ensuremath-for-math-macro)

Comment: You can also invoke this as `\V x`, which I find a bit nicer at times: `\V c = \V a \times \V b`.

Answer (score 5):

Define a command that takes an argument. No need to use a non-letter name: If your vector names are a single letter, you don't need to type the braces:

```
\newcommand\V[1]{\ensuremath{\mathbf{#1}}}

 \[ \V w = a\V v_0 + \V u  \]
```

You do need a space after \V (unless you use a non-letter instead of V).

Comment: Or even better, `\def\V:#1{\mathbf{#1}} $\V:ab\times\V:{ab}$`

Comment: Avoiding the space is precisely the reason to use a non-letter name.

Answer (score 3):

When automating tex (speeding-up workflow is a particular case) — there's always two approaches:

1. automate the problem in tex
2. automate the problem in text-editor

When talking about minimising key strokes — you can't get shorter then a single key stroke, and that is possible with automating text-editor.

For example, here's an Emacs function which does what you want:

```
(defun tex-make-vector ()
  "If there's a selection -- wrap this with '\mathbf{' and '}'
   and put the point to the end.  Otherwise -- put the point
   between '\mathbf{' and '}'

   Also: when not in math mode -- enclose the thing in dollars."

  (interactive)

  (let (start end
              (delim "")
              (jump 1)
              )

    (when (not (texmathp))
      (setq delim "$")
      (setq jump 2)
      )

    (if (use-region-p)
        (progn
          (setq start (region-beginning))
          (setq end (region-end))

          (narrow-to-region start end)

          (goto-char (point-min))
          (insert (concat delim "\\mathbf{"))

          (goto-char (point-max))
          (insert (concat "}" delim))
          (widen)
          )

      (progn
        (insert (concat delim "\\mathbf{}" delim))
        (backward-char jump)
        )
      )
))
```

You can bind it to a key:

```
(define-key LaTeX-mode-map (kbd "C-v") 'tex-make-vector)
```

and you'll be able to insert a vector with a single key stroke.

The bad thing with "automating with text-editor" is always the same: it is not as modular than defining a `\newcommand` and using it. But using the custom command can also be fastened with text-editor.