# Multiple paragraphs break custom command

Tags: macros, paragraphs

first of all sorry if the question seems repetitive: I have tried to find a solution in previously asked questions but none of the hints provided seems to work for me.

Here is my situation. I am writing a new class to typeset my thesis (and hopefully help other students who would like to use LaTeX instead of Hangul) by customizing the memoir package.

Everything ran smoothly until I became stuck in this: I have a number of custom commands that define variables which are then output by the command `\prelims` (see code below).

```
\newcommand*{\supervisor}[1]{\gdef\KNUsupervisor{#1}}
\newcommand*{\department}[1]{\gdef\KNUdepartment{#1}}
\newcommand*{\major}[1]{\gdef\KNUmajor{#1}}
\newcommand*{\degree}[1]{\gdef\KNUdegree{#1}}

%%% \asbtractEN
\newcommand*{\abstractEN}[1]
{
  \gdef\KNUabstractEN
  {
    {
      \begin{center}
      \@title
      \vspace{1em}

      \@author
      \vspace{1em}

      School of \KNUdepartment \\
      Major in \KNUmajor \\
      The Graduate School \\
      (Supervised by Professor \KNUsupervisor)
      \end{center}
      \vspace{2em}

      (Abstract)
      \vspace{1em}

     \mbox{#1}
    }
  }
}

\newcommand{\prelims}{
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents \newpage
\listoffigures \newpage
\listoftables \newpage
\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}
\KNUabstractEN

\mainmatter
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}
}
```

My problem is that when specifying an abstract consisting of multiple paragraphs, such as

```
\abstractEN{
Par1

Par2
}
```

the compiler kindly spits at me with the "usual" `Paragraph ended before \abstractEN was complete.`

I have tried putting the argument in a separate block, in a box, and even in a minipage, but the error persists.

Any helpful soul around?

P.S. Any errors in English in the abstract command are strictly required by our University's template -.-

Comment: Remove the `*` from `\newcommand*{\abstractEN}`. See [What's the difference between \newcommand and \newcommand*?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1050/whats-the-difference-between-newcommand-and-newcommand)

Comment: Oh my... can't believe I didn't spot it. Thanks, and please post the comment as an answer so that I can upvote it.

Comment: This also teaches a lesson: too much copy and paste ruins your life! :)

Comment: You also need `\long` before your `\gdef`

Comment: @NeXuS: I have added an answer. And welcome to TeX.SX!

Comment: @cyberSingularity Thanks, unfortunately I just realized that I cannot upvote, since I don't have enough rep here yet!

Answer (score 5):

In TeX terminology, this is because your commands are not defined as `\long` so do not permit paragraph breaks in their arguments, because you have defined them with `\newcommand*` instead of `\newcommand`.

If using `\def` and variants to define commands that take arguments (and want them to accept paragraph breaks also), one needs to use the `\long` prefix. Andrew Swann pointed out that you use `\gdef` so should be aware of this, but none of the commands defined with `\gdef` in your example appear to take arguments, so do not require this.

Solution: Remove the `*` from `\newcommand*{\abstractEN}`.

See [What's the difference between `\newcommand` and `\newcommand*`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1050/whats-the-difference-between-newcommand-and-newcommand)
The answers to that question explain why the non-`\long` form can be useful.