# What is the difference between \newenvironment and \newenvironment*?

Tags: environments, starred-version

I vaguely seem to recall reading that `\newenvironment*` gives better spacing than `\newenvironment`, but I don't recall any details and I can't seem to find a reference by searching.  What is the difference between these two, and when should one be used rather than the other?

[Note: I'll be happy for this to be closed as a duplicate, as long as someone can point to the question of which it is a duplicate; I cannot seem to locate such a question.]

Comment: The relation is the same as between `\newcommand` and `\newcommand*`: if there are arguments to `\begin{foo}`, then they are allowed to contain empty lines in the former case and aren't in the latter. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1050/whats-the-difference-between-newcommand-and-newcommand

Comment: @egreg: So, to check my understanding: If we are defining a new environment called `foo`, then using `\newenvironment*` rather than `\newenvironment` will have no effect on what is allowed in between `\begin{foo}` and `\end{foo}`, but will have an effect on what is allowed inside arguments to `\begin{foo}`. And there is no effect on spacing. Is this correct?

Comment: @CharlesStaats Exactly right

Comment: So as not to encourage more close votes, there's been further discussion in chat to *not* close this question as a duplicate. See http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7216046#7216046 and following discussion.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The relation is the same as that between `\newcommand` and `\newcommand*`, which is covered in [What's the difference between \newcommand and \newcommand*?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1050/whats-the-difference-between-newcommand-and-newcommand)

There's no influence on the environment's behavior, except as regards to the *arguments* to `\begin{envname}`.

Specifically, if you say

```
\newenvironment{foo}[1]
 {something with #1}
 {something else}
```

you're allowed to say

```
\begin{foo}{An argument 

  with a blank line}
The environment's contents

With perhaps a blank line
\end{foo}
```

while `\newenvironment*{foo}` wouldn't allow this and the *argument* should not contain any blank line (or `\par` command), but the environment's contents has no limitation (other than those possibly imposed by its definition).