# Macro for Declaring Variables in Class Files

Tags: macros, best-practices, documentclass-writing

I'm designing a new LaTeX class, and trying to write a convenient helper command for declaring new 'variables' for use in the class.

Specifically, say I want to use a variable called `\foo`. I'd like an author to be able to write `\foo{bar}`, and then be able to use `\@foo` in the class file (which would itself expand to `bar`. This can be accomplished with the following code:

```
\let\@foo\relax
\def\foo#1{\def\@foo{#1}}
```

and the author can define it with `\foo{bar}`. I want to create a helper command that allows the variable declaration to be done with a command like `\DeclareAuthorVariable`, which I would use in the LaTeX class file to declare variables. For example, I would like to be able to write `\DeclareAuthorVariable{foo}` in the class file instead of the ugly two line mess above. I've tried a number of different approaches, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to do this, since the commands that I'm trying to replace themselves involve arguments. I'm wondering if anyone knows how to do this or if it isn't possible? Thanks!

(Also, apologies, I'm very new to LaTeX class design!)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I'd add also some functions. You can declare a variable to be mandatory or optional; for instance `title` might be mandatory, while `subtitle` only optional. I propose the syntax

```
\DeclareAuthorVariable*{title}   % mandatory
\DeclareAuthorVariable{subtitle} % optional
```

Here is the code. Change the `ting` prefix to what suits you best.

```
% Do the branching between * and normal version
\newcommand{\DeclareAuthorVariable}{%
  \@ifstar{\ting@DeclareAuthorVariable{\ting@mandatory@var}}
          {\ting@DeclareAuthorVariable{\ting@optional@var}}%
}

% The main command; the internal version of \foo is \ting@foo
% The macro \ting@foo is initialized to give an error or an info
% message when used, so if the user doesn't provide a value for a
% mandatory variable, we'll catch the issue
\newcommand{\ting@DeclareAuthorVariable}[2]{%
  \@namedef{ting@#2}{#1{#2}}%
  \@namedef{#2}##1{\@namedef{ting@#2}{##1}}%
}
% The error and info messages
\newcommand{\ting@mandatory@var}[1]{%
  \ClassError{ting}
    {Missing value for mandatory variable
     \expandafter\string\csname#1\endcsname}
    {You have to provide a value with
     \expandafter\string\csname#1\endcsname{...}}%
}
\newcommand{\ting@optional@var}[1]{%
  \ClassInfo{ting}
    {Missing value for optional variable
     \expandafter\string\csname#1\endcsname}%
}

%%% Define two variables
\DeclareAuthorVariable*{title}
\DeclareAuthorVariable{subtitle}
```

If you need to branch according to a variable having been given a value or not, you can modify `\ting@DeclareAuthorVariable`:

```
\newcommand{\ting@DeclareAuthorVariable}[2]{%
  \@namedef{ting@#2}{#1{#2}}%
  \@namedef{#2}##1{\@namedef{ting@#2}{##1}\@namedef{ting@#2@defined}{}}%
}
```

and add

```
\newcommand{\@ifauthorvariable}[3]{\@ifundefined{ting@#1@defined}{#3}{#2}}
```

so that you can say something like

```
\@ifauthorvariable{subtitle}
  {\vspace{3ex}\textsc{\ting@subtitle}\par\vspace{3ex}}
  {\vspace{1ex}---\par\vspace{1ex}}
```

(Here I assume that the title page will be set under `\centering`; the subtitle or, if missing, a dash would be printed.)

Comment: Wow, thanks so much! This is not only an excellent answer in its own right, but provides great insight into the correct stylistic and robustness concerns in package design.

Comment: One question though, why do you end the intermediate lines in your functions with %?

Comment: @MichaelTingley Most of these `%` are irrelevant here; but it's a good habit to put them where a space might creep in. You don't need them between arguments to a macro, but only at the end. So no `%` is needed after `\ClassInfo{ting}` because TeX will be looking for the next argument to `\ClassInfo`, so skipping spaces; after the second argument to `\ClassInfo` it's good to have one.

Comment: Any advice for how to check if one of these optional variables is defined? Thanks

Comment: @MichaelTingley Are you meaning a check that `\DefineAuthorVariable{foo}` doesn't redefine an existing `\foo` macro?

Comment: No, something like `\IsDefined{foo}{<true code>}{<false code>}`, which would execute the relevant code segment contingent on whether the author provided a value for the optional variable `foo` or not. It doesn't seem like I can do this with `\ifx\ting@foo\@empty`, since `foo` is initialized to give an error (or maybe I'm doing it wrong?). At the same time, I really like having the default error logging that you've provided.

Comment: Correct me, if I'm wrong, but I would use `\newcommand*` with an asterisk for the additional error-checking [see here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1057/44278). Also things to have a look at, when writing more involved macros, are `\expandafter` and all its expansion-order affecting friends. I already use very similar constructs in my current project, but your answer provided valuable ideas on how I could improve on my class.

Comment: @Valryne It depends on what's expected in the argument to the command. Using `\newcommand*` may indeed make sense when simple words are to be passed and not complete paragraphs.

Answer (score 9):

```
\makeatletter
\def\DeclareAuthorVariable#1{\@namedef{#1}##1{\@namedef{@#1}{##1}}}

\DeclareAuthorVariable{foo}

\show\foo

\foo{abc}

\show\@foo

\stop
```

Produces

```
> \foo=macro:
#1->\@namedef {@foo}{#1}.
l.7 \show\foo

? 
> \@foo=macro:
->abc.
l.11 \show\@foo

? 
 )
No pages of output.
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to study the [`KOMA-classes`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/koma-script) and their macro `\newkomavar`.

Comment: `\newkomavar` is only available in the `scrlttr2` class