# siunitx: Error while including value

Tags: siunitx, input

A value is saved in a file (`value.txt`, let's say).
The command

```
\SI{\input{value.txt}}{\someunit}
```

gives the error:

```
Argument of \input has an extra }
```

How can I read numbers from an external file and use them with `\SI`?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Comment: If you are reading data from a table, then `\input` is not the correct approach: look at `datatool` or `pgfplotstable`.

Comment: @dPol, Instead of including the answer in your post, you should accept a given answer instead.

Comment: @FooBar thanks for your answer, it inspired my "answer", of course. I thought that my change was quite deep and therefore it deserved to be posted as a separete answer. Unfortunately I could not answer to my own question.

Comment: Comments are not for discussion of these kind of things, but this website works in a question-answer manner. Even "inspiring" answers are answers and should not be mixed with the questions. Currently your question is no question but a "statement". If it'S OK for you I can edit my answer with your adapted code.

Comment: no problem. No copyright on it ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to read the file with TeX commands:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\def\inputval{0}
\newread\inputFile
\let\oldSI\SI

\renewcommand*{\SI}[3][]{%
  \IfFileExists{#2}{
    \openin\inputFile=#2
    \read\inputFile to \inputval
    \closein\inputFile
    \oldSI[#1]{\inputval}{#3}
  }{\oldSI[#1]{#2}{#3}}
}

\begin{document}
  \SI{value.txt}{\metre} % use \SI like always, but with input file
  \oldSI{5}{\metre}      % \oldSI does work like the old \SI ;)
\end{document}
```

Of course, this could be heavily improved (check if the format is correct, etc.), but that's the way to go.

Comment: I include tens of values in a single document. Is it possible to avoid 3 lines and 2 new variables definition?

Comment: You can make the file reading code a command, like `\newcommand*{\readNumber} [1] {here the code}`, where the only argument is the file to be read.

Comment: I edited the answer with a command to read the file.

Comment: @FooBar I've moved the `\newread` line outside the definition, where it's wrong.

Comment: Why the \def and \newread can't be inside the newcommand? and why did you put * after newcommand?

Comment: These are big questions on their own and should not be discussed in the comments (and I'm sure the answers can be found on this site already).

Comment: @dPol see [What's the difference between `\newcommand` and `\newcommand*`?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1050/whats-the-difference-between-newcommand-and-newcommand)

Comment: I edited my original answer with dPol's adapted solution to be in sync with the question.

Comment: Very good answer, but I had to add `%` at the end of each line of the command to prevent extra spaces before and after the number