# How to make a caption visible in a newly defined lstenvironment?

Tags: listings

I have a new `lstenvironment` defined like this:

```
\lstnewenvironment{xml}
{\lstset{language=xml, basicstyle=\ttfamily, frame=single, captionpos=b}}
{}
```

Then I want to apply it in my code:

```
\begin{xml}[label=base,caption=A configuration XML file.]
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<config>
    <connecting>
        <url>something</url>
        <user>username</user>
        <password>password</password>
    </connecting>
</config>
\end{xml}
```

In the output, I would expect caption printed at the bottom of the listing, however, it is not. Some suggestions? Do I need to include something more within `\lstset`?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You may have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your definition of the environment `xml` needs an optional argument.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstnewenvironment{xml}[1][]
{\lstset{language=xml, basicstyle=\ttfamily, frame=single, captionpos=b,#1}}
{}
\begin{document}
\begin{xml}[label=base,caption=A configuration XML file.]
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<config>
    <connecting>
        <url>something</url>
        <user>username</user>
        <password>password</password>
    </connecting>
</config>
\end{xml}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It works, thanks. However, could someone explain me the meaning of these optional arguments [1][] when defining \lstnewenvironment? I went through the documentation for listing, but still couldnt figure it out.

Comment: @MichalB: See: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1050/whats-the-difference-between-newcommand-and-newcommand/1057#1057