# What is the difference between \def and \newcommand (Part II)?

Tags: macros, tex-core

A previous question [What is the difference between \def and \newcommand?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/655/what-is-the-difference-between-def-and-newcommand) has discussed the difference between `\def` and `\newcommand` at some length. However, I cannot find in that discussion an explanation of the following phenomenon.

This code prints **Empty**:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\def\foo{}
\ifx\foo\empty Empty\else Not empty\fi
\end{document}
```

This code prints **Not empty**:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\newcommand\foo{}
\ifx\foo\empty Empty\else Not empty\fi
\end{document}
```

The only difference is that one has `\def` and the other has `\newcommand`. What's going on?

Comment: `\empty` and `\foo` are different. `\foo` is defined as `\long\def\foo{}` which is different than `\def\empty{}`. Try `\newcommand*\foo{}` instead.

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1050/whats-the-difference-between-newcommand-and-newcommand

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel may as well make that an answer, as it is the answer:-)

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel -- might be worth mentioning that `\newcommand*\foo{}` gives the same result as `\def`.  should be obvious, but ...

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Goodness me, (La)TeX sure is subtle! I posted a new answer to the old ["newcommand vs. def" question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/655/what-is-the-difference-between-def-and-newcommand), as this point hadn't actually been made there.

Comment: As you've posted the answer at the other question, maybe this one should now be closed as a duplicate of it.

Comment: @AndrewStacey Happy to. Or I could just delete this question altogether?

Comment: @JohnWickerson Duplicates do have their place as they make it easier to find the main question.  I would only go for deletion if the question shouldn't have been asked here at all (meaning, if the duplicate hadn't already been here).