# Change caption name of an appendix

Tags: floats, captions, appendices, naming

I want to change the caption name of a figure for an appendix. For example I have

`\caption{This is a supplemental figure.}`

and by default the caption appears as

```
Figure 1: This is a supplemental figure.
```

However I want

```
Figure S1 - This is a supplemental figure.
```

I tried this

`\renewcommand{\figurename}{Figure S}`

but it adds a space in between and results in

```
Figure S 1 - This is a supplemental figure.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add this to your document preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macto\appendix{\renewcommand{\thefigure}{S\arabic{figure}}}
\makeatother
```

A MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}

\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\appendix{\renewcommand{\thefigure}{S\arabic{figure}}\setcounter{figure}{0}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\caption{Not in Appendix}
\end{figure}

\appendix

\begin{figure}
\caption{In Appendix}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

I would put the letter into the number:

```
\renewcommand*{\thefigure}{S\arabic{figure}}
```

Then also referencing works. `\ref` reports the number including the letter.

Comment: What is the difference between `\renewcomand{\thefigure}...` and `\renewcomand*{\thefigure}...` ?

Comment: @LeonardoSaravia: See question ["What's the difference between \newcommand and \newcommand*?"](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1050/16967).

Answer (score 0):

This would work if using the `appendices` environment:

```
\g@addto@macro\appendices{\renewcommand{\thefigure}{S\arabic{figure}}\setcounter{figure}{0}}
```

Latex code below:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{appendix}

\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\appendices{\renewcommand{\thefigure}{S\arabic{figure}}\setcounter{figure}{0}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\caption{Not in Appendix}
\end{figure}

\begin{appendices}

\begin{figure}
\caption{In Appendix}
\end{figure}

\end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\g@addto@macro\appendices` and not `\g@addto@macro\appendix`