# Defaulting to clever references

Tags: cross-referencing, cleveref

I would like to redefine `\ref` to behave like `\cref` while still allowing `\ref*` to be used for the standard behavior of `\ref`. Here is my attempt to achieve this; I would like to use the commented lines instead of the uncommented lines, but unfortunately I get an error. My reference for creating starred commands was the following: https://texfaq.org/FAQ-cmdstar

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{cleveref}
    
    \let\oldref\ref
    \renewcommand{\ref}{%
        \makeatletter
            \@ifstar
                \oldref%
                \cref%
        \makeatother
    }

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    \label{eqn:2.2.4}
    2 + 2 = 4
\end{equation}

\oldref{eqn:2.2.4}

\cref{eqn:2.2.4}

% \ref{eqn:2.2.4}

% \ref*{eqn:2.2.4}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Do not put `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` inside the `\renewcommand` (which fails for two different reasons) but outside of it: `\makeatletter\renewcommand{\ref}{\@ifstar\oldref\cref}\makeatother`.

Comment: Note that the package `hyperref` defines `\ref*` to not produce a link, so you could be in trouble if you load this package.

Comment: Why would you want to use `\ref` instead of `\cref`? The semantics are clearly different, someone not familiar with your change will have a difficult time parsing your LaTeX code.

Answer (score 2):

Do not put `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` inside the `\renewcommand`. This fails for two reasons:

1. `\@ifstar` sees `\makeatother` as the next character and not a `*` which may or may not follow.
2. When TeX processes the contents of the definition the catcodes of `@` are already read (and set to 12 (other)). (So you actually define it as `\@` followed by the letters `ifstar`.

The correct definition would be

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\ref}{\@ifstar\oldref\cref}
\makeatother
```

(For the `*` used here refer to [What's the difference between \newcommand and \newcommand*?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1050/16595))