# \intertext doesn't play nice with \paragraph

Tags: align, paragraphs

I have the following test case:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
    \section{Test}
    \paragraph{Group A:}
    \begin{align*}
        E &= mc^2\\
        E &= \hbar\omega
      \intertext{\paragraph{Group B:}}
        F &= ma\\
        F &= mv\frac{dv}{dx}
    \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

I would expect this to produce the paragraph title "Group A:", followed by two energy expressions, followed by the paragraph title "Group B:", followed by two force expressions.
When I use two `align*` blocks instead of `intertext` then this works, but in my actual document (where the equations are more complicated), the equations are obviously not aligned across the blocks.

If I remove the `\paragraph` from the `\intertext`, then I get the expected result (but the "Group B:" text is obviously not formatted as I want).

The specific output that I get from TexMaker looks as follows:

## Log:

```
LOG FILE :
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-1.40.10 (MiKTeX 2.8) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2013.7.16) 16 JUL 2013 15:42
(etc)
```

## Output:

> ### 1 Test
>
> #### Group A:
>
> E = mc²
>
> E = hw
>
> #### Group A:
>
> F = ma
>
> F = mv dv/dt
>
> #### Group A:

...which is obviously not what I want!

## Solution (thanks to egreg):

Prelude:

```
\newcommand{\group}[1]{\noalign{\noindent\textbf{#1}}}
```

Document:

```
  E &= mc^2\\
  E &= \hbar\omega\\
\group{Group B:}\\
  F &= ma\\
  F &= mv\frac{dv}{dx}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You're abusing `\paragraph`, in my opinion. Why not just `\noindent\textbf{Group A:}`?

Comment: Hi!  I normally use Word2000, so I'm used to using heading styles for headings, rather than setting the formatting manually.  I chose Tex for this since I want some nice vector diagrams (via Tikz), and originally had two `\paragraph`s and two `align*` blocks.  I'll try that `\noindent\textbf` way now.  Thanks!

Comment: `\paragraph` is actually the name for the sectional level below `\subsubsection`. You can define your own macro, say `\newcommand{\group}[1]{\par\noindent\textbf{Group #1:}}` and use `\group{A}` instead of specifying formatting instructions in the document.

Comment: @egreg:  That gives the right formatting, but the alignment is off.  Wrapping it in `\noalign` worked!  Thanks!

Comment: @egreg: Just out of curiosity, how am I abusing `\paragraph`? -- ah just seen your answer, thanks!

Comment: @MarkKCowan LaTeX users would also expect to use sectioning commands for sections, but not inside the middle of an alignment!

Comment: @JosephWright:  Thanks, I'm producing a list of equations that are separated into small named sections by usage, and should all be aligned at the `=`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `\paragraph` macro is not a general purpose macro for setting things in boldface. It's a sectional command, in the hierarchy

```
\section
\subsection
\subsubsection
\paragraph
\subparagraph
```

In your case I'd define a special macro for this kind of secondary header.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}

\newcommand{\group}[1]{%
  \par\noindent\textbf{Group #1:}
}

\begin{document}
\section{Test}
\group{A}
\begin{align*}
  E &= mc^2\\
  E &= \hbar\omega
\shortintertext{\group{B}}
  F &= ma\\
  F &= mv\frac{dv}{dx}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

In this way you don't have formatting instructions in the file and the `\group` macro represents an instance of an abstract secondary header; you can modify the appearance just by acting on the definition.

For better results, `\shortintertext` from `mathtools` should be used, because the spacing it provides are not as dramatic as those produced by `\intertext`.

[image]

Comment: When I try putting `\par` directly inside the intertext it complains about the paragraph ending before `align*`. But it works if I have the `\par` inside another command like the `\group{}` command here then it works perfectly. Even something like `\newcommand\gpar\par` is enough (you can then use `\gpar` inside an intertext); I can't understand why this is the case though.

Comment: @codebeard `align` doesn't accept `\par` inside it, even if it is in `\intertext`.

Comment: yes, that's what confuses me. I guess there are two questions here: 1) why does `\renamedpar` work but `\par` does not, and 2) why does `align` try to prevent `par` in the first place?

Comment: @codebeard When a macro is not `\long` (which is what the inner macros for `align` are) it doesn't accept `\par` in its argument (as well as an empty line), but it accepts any other token, even if it is equivalent to `\par`. See [What's the difference between `\newcommand` and `\newcommand*`?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1050/)