# Vertical space before list environment within a macro

Tags: macros, lists, vertical-alignment, itemize

***UPDATE***

My problem comes down to the following: vertical space is added before the `\item`s of a list within a macro. The layout I want to use is based on the classicthesis-styled CV (currvita) template by Alessandro Plasmati and the defined commands (`\MarginText` and `\Description`) should produce a margin text that is aligned vertically with the first line of the `\Description` text.

However, when using lists, vertical space is added before the list. How can I suppress this? I already tried `\setlength{topskip}{0pt}` and also the space controls added by the `enumitem` package.

Why do lists behave like this?

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\reversemarginpar
\newcommand{\MarginText}[1]{\marginpar{\raggedleft#1}}
\newcommand{\Description}[1]{#1}

\begin{document}
\Description{\MarginText{Papers}
\begin{itemize}
\item a bibitem
\item another one
\end{itemize}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

*Old Version*

When I use `\bibentry` in the classicthesis-styled CV, the entries are listed after a line break, however I want the `\bibentry` *next* to the category (e.g. papers, conferences, posters etc.). Also, the bibliography gets listed below (which I don't want)—how can I change this? See an example in the uploaded screenshot and the MWE below.

[image]

> **MWE**

```
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PACKAGES AND OTHER DOCUMENT CONFIGURATIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[nochapters]{classicthesis} 
\usepackage[LabelsAligned]{currvita} 

%***********************
% FONTS
%***********************
\usepackage{fontspec,xunicode}
\setmainfont[Ligatures={Common,Historical}]{Adobe Caslon Pro}
\setsansfont[Mapping=tex-text,Scale=MatchLowercase]{Futura}


%***********************
% LAYOUT
%***********************
\reversemarginpar % Move the margin to the left of the page 
\newcommand{\MarginText}[1]{\marginpar{\raggedleft\itshape\small#1}\marginparsep0pt} % New command defining the margin text style

\usepackage{xcolor}\renewcommand{\cvheadingfont}{\Huge\sf{\bf}\color{Maroon}} 

\usepackage{hyperref}

\newlength{\datebox}\settowidth{\datebox}{Long  2011} % Set the width of the date box in each block

\newcommand{\NewEntry}[3]{\noindent\hangindent=2em\hangafter=0 \parbox{\datebox}{\small \sffamily \textit{#1}}\hspace{1em} #2 #3 % Define a command for each new block - change spacing and font sizes here: #1 is the left margin, #2 is the italic date field and #3 is the position/employer/location field
\vspace{0.5em}} % Add some white space after each new entry

\newcommand{\Description}[1]{\hangindent=2em\hangafter=0\noindent\raggedright\footnotesize{#1}\par\normalsize\vspace{1em}} % Define a command for descriptions of each entry - change spacing and font sizes here




% bib stuff
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage{bibentry}
\nobibliography*


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------






\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty} % Stop the page count at the bottom of the first page

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   NAME AND CONTACT INFORMATION SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{cv}{\spacedallcaps{The Applicant}}\vspace{1.5em} % Your name

\noindent\spacedlowsmallcaps{Personal Information}\vspace{0.5em} % Personal information heading

\NewEntry{*}{\textit{Born in the USA,}}{19 July 2013} % Birthplace and date 

\NewEntry{email}{\href{mailto:me@post.com}{me@post.com}}% Email address

\NewEntry{address}{Ice cream street 3, 0188484 Popsicle, Alaska} % Personal website

\NewEntry{phone}{(H) +33 (0) 3455 9222\ \ $\cdotp$\ \ (M) +33 (0) 455 1116661} % Phone number(s)

\vspace{1em} % Extra white space between the personal information section and goal

\noindent\spacedlowsmallcaps{Goal}\vspace{1em} % Goal heading, could be used for a quotation or short profile instead

\vspace{2em} % Goal text

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   EDUCATION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\spacedlowsmallcaps{Education}\vspace{1em}


\NewEntry{2009--2013}{University XYZ}

\Description{\MarginText{Ph.\,D.} Info, info, info\ \ $\cdotp$\ \ School: School of Physics \newline Thesis: \textit{"Title title"} Description: ... \\ Advisors: Dr.\,XC \textsc{Hellloo}}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PUBLICATIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\spacedlowsmallcaps{Publications}\vspace{1em}

\Description{\MarginText{Papers}
\begin{itemize}
\item \bibentry{Bohr:1923tl}
\item \bibentry{Bohr:1923tl}  
\end{itemize}
}

\Description{\MarginText{Posters}
Text text text
\begin{itemize}
\item \bibentry{Bohr:1923tl}
\item \bibentry{Bohr:1923tl}  
\end{itemize}
}

\Description{\MarginText{Conferences}
\bibentry{Bohr:1923tl}
}

%------------------------------------------------

\end{cv}

%\nocite{*} 
\bibliographystyle{plainnat} 
\bibliography{lib-x}

\end{document}
```

> **lib-x.bib**

```
@article{Bohr:1923tl,
author = {Bohr, N},
title = {{The structure of the atom}},
journal = {Nature},
year = {1923},
volume = {112},
pages = {29--44}
}
```

Comment: You could use the `marginnote` package, use it to define `\newcommand{\MarginText}[1]{\marginnote{\raggedleft#1}}`, and call it as part of the first item: `\begin{itemize}\item\MarginText{Papers}a bibitem ...`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a version for your updated problem.  I use `enumitem` to easily kill the top spacing on the list, and before the list I ensure that we back up vertically (this code is now placed in the list options).  Note the `\leavevmode` added to the `\MarginText` command, for consistency of spacing:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}

\reversemarginpar

\newcommand{\MarginText}[1]{\leavevmode\marginpar{\raggedleft#1}\ignorespaces}
\newcommand{\Description}[1]{#1}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\Description{\MarginText{Papers}
\begin{itemize}[topsep=0pt,partopsep=0pt,before=\vspace*{\dimexpr-\baselineskip-\parskip},after=\vspace*{\baselineskip}]
\item a bibitem
\item another one
\end{itemize}
}

\Description{\MarginText{Other}
Some text

And some more}

\end{document}
```

In your example you would probably want to define a new list type and use it when necessary:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[nochapters]{classicthesis} 
\usepackage[LabelsAligned]{currvita} 

%***********************
% FONTS
%***********************
\usepackage{fontspec,xunicode}
%\setmainfont[Ligatures={Common,Historical}]{Adobe Caslon Pro}
%\setsansfont[Mapping=tex-text,Scale=MatchLowercase]{Futura}


%***********************
% LAYOUT
%***********************
\reversemarginpar % Move the margin to the left of the page 
\newcommand{\MarginText}[1]{\leavevmode\marginpar{\raggedleft\itshape\small#1}\ignorespaces} % New command defining the margin text style

\usepackage{xcolor}\renewcommand{\cvheadingfont}{\Huge\sf{\bf}\color{Maroon}} 

\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{thislineitemize}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[thislineitemize]{label=\textbullet,topsep=0pt,partopsep=0pt,before=\vspace*{\dimexpr-\baselineskip-\parskip},after=\vspace*{\baselineskip}}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\newlength{\datebox}\settowidth{\datebox}{Long  2011} % Set the width of the date box in each block

\newcommand{\NewEntry}[3]{\noindent\hangindent=2em\hangafter=0 \parbox{\datebox}{\small \sffamily \textit{#1}}\hspace{1em} #2 #3 % Define a command for each new block - change spacing and font sizes here: #1 is the left margin, #2 is the italic date field and #3 is the position/employer/location field
\vspace{0.5em}} % Add some white space after each new entry

\newcommand{\Description}[1]{\bgroup\hangindent=2em\hangafter=0\noindent
\raggedright\footnotesize#1\par\egroup\vspace{1em}} % Define a command for descriptions of each entry - change spacing and font sizes here

% bib stuff
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage{bibentry}
\nobibliography*

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty} % Stop the page count at the bottom of the first page

\begin{cv}{\spacedallcaps{The Applicant}}\vspace{1.5em} % Your name

\noindent\spacedlowsmallcaps{Personal Information}\vspace{0.5em} % Personal information heading

\NewEntry{*}{\textit{Born in the USA,}}{19 July 2013} % Birthplace and date 

\NewEntry{email}{\href{mailto:me@post.com}{me@post.com}}% Email address

\NewEntry{address}{Ice cream street 3, 0188484 Popsicle, Alaska} % Personal website

\NewEntry{phone}{(H) +33 (0) 3455 9222\ \ $\cdotp$\ \ (M) +33 (0) 455 1116661} % Phone number(s)

\vspace{1em} % Extra white space between the personal information section and goal

\noindent\spacedlowsmallcaps{Goal}\vspace{1em} % Goal heading, could be used for a quotation or short profile instead

\vspace{2em} % Goal text

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   EDUCATION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\spacedlowsmallcaps{Education}\vspace{1em}


\NewEntry{2009--2013}{University XYZ}

\Description{\MarginText{Ph.\,D.} Info, info, info\ \ $\cdotp$\ \ School: School of Physics \newline Thesis: \textit{``Title title''} Description: \dots \\ Advisors: Dr.\,XC \textsc{Hellloo}}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PUBLICATIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\spacedlowsmallcaps{Publications}\vspace{1em}

\Description{\MarginText{Papers}
\begin{thislineitemize}
\item \bibentry{Bohr:1923tl}
\item \bibentry{Bohr:1923tl}  
\end{thislineitemize}
}

\Description{\MarginText{Posters}
Text text text
\begin{itemize}
\item \bibentry{Bohr:1923tl}
\item \bibentry{Bohr:1923tl}  
\end{itemize}
}

\Description{\MarginText{Conferences}
\bibentry{Bohr:1923tl}
}

%------------------------------------------------

\end{cv}

%\nocite{*} 
\bibliographystyle{plainnat} 
\bibliography{lib-x}

\end{document}
```

As to the general "Why", list environments as standard start on a newline.  This is usually desirable as you don't have worry about whether the call falls inside a paragraph or not.  But in some situations it is not what one wants.

Comment: This doesn't work because I use the same commands with normal text environment (i.e. without lists) and then the second paragraph of the text overlaps with the first paragraph, e.g. `\Description{\MarginText{Papers}
Just Text without any lists. \And the second paragraph.}`

Comment: You can move the backspacing code around.  I have rewritten the answer with it now placed in the list.

Comment: ok, thanks! actually, I just could have defined two commands instead of one. your first version for lists and the old version for normal text...

Answer (score 2):

To have no references list at the end, instead of `\bibliography{lib-x}` put `\nobibliography{lib-x}`. Source: http://gking.harvard.edu/files/bibentry2.pdf

The reason you have the line break in the "Conferences" section is because you put a line break in there, i.e. you wrote

```
\Description{\MarginText{Conferences}

\bibentry{Bohr:1923tl}
}
```

but you can remove the line break by

```
\Description{\MarginText{Conferences}
\bibentry{Bohr:1923tl}
}
```

In my test, this messed with the position of the `\MarginText`, but I don't know why. I think the reason there's a line break in the "Papers" section has to do with the `itemize`, but that could be wrong.

Comment: Thank you for the \nobibliogrpahy{} solution, darthbith!

Comment: It seems that when using the macro \newcommand, empty lines are not allowed which is strange, because technically it should do so. see [http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1050/whats-the-difference-between-newcommand-and-newcommand]

Comment: I don't understand what you mean... your problem is that you have extra empty lines, not that there aren't empty lines where you expect them, right?

Comment: yeah, i got lost, i guess. sorry for the confusion