# Faking minipage in a tabularx column eliminates space between table and following section

Tags: sectioning, tabularx, minipage

I'm typesetting a tabularx in which some of the cells in one column (of type `X`) contain itemize lists.  I don't like the excessive space above & below the lists (or even between the list items), so I'm using the trick from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6445/preventing-itemize-environment-to-insert-initial-vertical-space/6454#6454) to eliminate the upper vertical space and [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/126505/7280) to eliminate the lower (Trying to use the latter answer's advice for eliminating the upper vertical space didn't work).  Specifically, I've defined this command in the preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\compress}{\@minipagetrue}
\makeatother
```

and I've inserted `>{\compress}` before the `X` in the column specification.

On its own, this works fine, except that (a) the last row of the table contains regular text, not a list, and (b) the table is immediately followed by a `\section`.  These two facts together result in an output in which there is noticeably too little space between the table and the section header.  If I remove the last row of the table, leaving a row with a list as the new last row, or if I delete the `\section` command, or if I remove the `>{\compress}`, the spacing goes back to normal, but the first two aren't what I want to typeset, and the last results in the top lines of the rows not lining up.

Minimalish working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\compress}{\@minipagetrue}
\makeatother
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[itemize]{
    itemsep=0.15\baselineskip,
    parsep=0pt,
    % Trick from answer 126505; did not work:
    %before=\vspace*{\dimexpr-\baselineskip-\parskip},
    after=\vspace*{-\baselineskip}
}
\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{l>{\compress}X}
\textbf{Colors}   & \begin{itemize}
                    \item Red
                    \item Green
                    \item Blue
                    \end{itemize} \\
\textbf{Gems}     & \begin{itemize}
                    \item Ruby
                    \item Sapphire
                    \item Emerald
                    \end{itemize} \\
\textbf{Elements} & \begin{itemize}
                    \item Fire
                    \item Water
                    \item Earth
                    \end{itemize} \\
\textbf{Foo}      & Bar \\
\end{tabularx}

\section{Next Section}
Lorem ipsum\ldots

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: What about `\setlist[itemize]{
    itemsep=0.15\baselineskip,
    parsep=0pt,
    before=\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth},
    after=\end{minipage}
}`?

Comment: @leandriis: That works.  I should have thought of that....

Comment: You can also use `\newcommand{\uncompress}{\global\@minipagefalse}`

Comment: @JohnKormylo no need for `\global` (it is global already) and the name I used in my answer is nicer, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\compress}{\@minipagetrue}
\newcommand\ifyoudothatyoudbetterdothis{\@minipagefalse}
\makeatother
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[itemize]{
    itemsep=0.15\baselineskip,
    parsep=0pt,
    % Trick from answer 126505; did not work:
    %before=\vspace*{\dimexpr-\baselineskip-\parskip},
    after=\vspace*{-\baselineskip}
}
\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{l>{\compress}X<{\ifyoudothatyoudbetterdothis}}
\textbf{Colors}   & \begin{itemize}
                    \item Red
                    \item Green
                    \item Blue
                    \end{itemize} \\
\textbf{Gems}     & \begin{itemize}
                    \item Ruby
                    \item Sapphire
                    \item Emerald
                    \end{itemize} \\
\textbf{Elements} & \begin{itemize}
                    \item Fire
                    \item Water
                    \item Earth
                    \end{itemize} \\
\textbf{Foo}      & Bar \\
\end{tabularx}



\section{Next Section}
Lorem ipsum\ldots

\end{document}
```

`@minipage` is a *global* flag. If you set it true you need to ensure that it is set to false, otherwise you will affect some arbitrary unexpected part of the document, such as forcing a following section heading to act as if it is at the top of a page and not add vertical space.

If you have a list in the cell the list code will arrange to set the flag false but with just a bare paragraph you are leaving it true.

Safer than using `\@minipagetrue` directly would be to do as `minipage` does and use `\@setminipage` which is defined as

```
\def \@setminipage{%
  \@minipagetrue
  \everypar{\@minipagefalse\everypar{}}%
}
```

Then even your bare paragraph would set it false however you still need to set it false at the end (as `\endminipage` does) in case the cell is empty or just has a rule or in some other way avoids having a paragraph that triggers `\everypar`.