# Typographic issues in definitions of newcommands

Tags: math-mode, kerning

Sir, I have small issues with two newcommand

1. I have this definition that I do not like:

   ```
   \def\DDbar {\ensuremath{\kern -0.1em \stackrel{\kern 0.1em \textsf{\fontsize{5pt}{1em}\selectfont(---)}}{D}\kern -0.3em}\xspace}
   ```

   do you know how to improve it? What I need is something similar to this

   ```
   \def\Dbar    {\kern 0.2em\overline{\kern -0.2em \PD}{}\xspace}
   ```

   where, instead of a single bar, I want a bar within parentheses.
2. My second issue is with

   ```
   \def\sPlot  {\ensuremath{\hbox{$_s$}{\mathcal P}lot}\xspace}
   ```

   it shows what I want but why on earth do I need the `$_s$` inside an `\ensuremath`? Is that because of `\hbox`? If I take the `$$` away the command will not work in normal text writing.

Thank again for your precious help.

Comment: Can you submit a working example for the first part please?

Comment: For the second question (which might be better as a separate question): you need the math markers inside the hbox because tex goes back into restricted horizontal mode inside the hbox, so you need to turn on maths again to make the underscore work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are a `\parenbar` and `\xbar` commands for avoiding the bar cover too much its argument. The commands have an optional argument for adjusting the amount of shifting; for instance, if the symbol is upright, `\parenbar[0]{\Phi}` seems more adequate.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\DDbar{\parenbar{D}}
\newcommand{\parenbar}[2][4]{%
  \mkern#1mu
  \sbox0{$#2$}%
  \makebox[0pt][r]{\raisebox{\ht0}{$\scriptscriptstyle($}}%
  \overline{\mkern-#1mu#2\mkern-1mu}%
  \makebox[0pt][l]{\raisebox{\ht0}{$\scriptscriptstyle)$}}%
  \mkern1mu
}
\newcommand{\xbar}[2][4]{%
  \mkern#1mu
  \overline{\mkern-4mu#2\mkern-1mu}%
  \mkern1mu
}

\begin{document}
$X\DDbar X\xbar{D} X$

$\parenbar[1]{\Phi}$

$A\xbar{A}A$
\end{document}
```

[image]

For the second question, see Andrew Swann's answer:

```
\newcommand{\sPlot}{%
  {}_s\mathcal{P}\mkern-2mu\mathit{lot}%
}
```

without `\ensuremath` and `\xspace` is the way to go.

Comment: Thanks. Anyhow if I remove the `\ensuremath` and the `\ensuremath` when I am in normal mode (is it call this way?) and I write for example `\sPlot ciao` what I will see is the correct `sPlot` but no space between it and `ciao`, this is no good for me as I speak a lot about this `sPlot` and is never in an equation.

Comment: @leoredi you should write `$\sPlot$ ciao` or `\(\sPlot\) ciao`.

Comment: Sir, I understand that but, as I said, this is no good for me. I will use `\sPlot` solely in text mode. So, my question is if there is a better way of modifying the wonderful definition of @egreg s.t. I can use it without the `$` or the `\(\`. Thanks

Comment: @leoredi What's so difficult in typing `$\sPlot$`?

Comment: Nothing but its two more characters every time. Then I might as well put it in the definition no?

Answer (score 5):

Here are a couple of suggestions.

For the first command `\stackrel` causes the whole construction to be centered vertically, meaning that the `D` does not sit on the baseline.  Instead you can use `\overset` from the `amsmath` package.  Instead of switching to text mode for the emdash, you can use a LaTeX `\rule`:

```
 \rule[0.3ex]{1em}{0.4pt}
```

produces a rule `1em` long (like an emdash), with the standard line thickness of `0.4pt` but raised `0.3ex`.  Putting your bracketed expression in a `\smash` statement allows it to be lowered a bit closer to the `D`.

For the second command, no you do not need the `\hbox` maneuvers, just `{}_s` will do to produce the lowered `s`.  I'd don't like the mixed fonts for the word plot, but if you insist on this then write the last part as `\mathit{lot}` to get no math kerning, and then move it closer to the `P` with a negative kern.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xspace,amsmath}

\newcommand*{\DDbar}{\ensuremath{\overset{\smash[b]{(\rule[0.3ex]{1em}{0.4pt})}}D}\xspace}

\newcommand*{\sPlot}{\ensuremath{{}_s{\mathcal P}\mkern-2mu\mathit{lot}}\xspace}

\begin{document}

Text \DDbar text \sPlot.

\end{document}
```

By the way I am not a fan of the `\ensuremath...\xspace` combinations, I would prefer to just define math mode commands `\DDbar` etc. and then write `\( \DDbar \)` if I need somewhere in text.  I have also used `\newcommand*` instead of `\def` as egreg pointed out: `\newcommand` is a LaTeX user level command and will alert you if the command is already defined, see [What is the difference between \def and \newcommand?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/655/15925) and [What's the difference between \newcommand and \newcommand*?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1050/15925).

Comment: I'm not a fan of `\def` either. +1 anyway

Comment: @egreg Nor I.  I had intended to change that...now its included.

Comment: The problem I had with this is that when I put `\DDbar` in text it is way too high and will move the entire line down a bit

Comment: Your question was not very precise, so the above was a first shot an answer.  egreg's solution provides a result that probably suits your situation better.

Answer (score 1):

Here's some possibilities:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\usepackage{xspace}
\begin{document}
\def\Dbar    {\kern 0.2em\overline{\kern -0.2em D}{}\xspace}
\( \Dbar \)

\def\useanchorwidth{T}
\def\DDbar {\stackon[-1.5pt]{$D$}{\ensuremath{\kern.18em \textsf{\fontsize{6pt}{1em}\selectfont{\tiny(}---{\tiny)}}}}\xspace}
\(\DDbar\)

\def\sPlot  {\ensuremath\ThisStyle{\hbox{$\SavedStyle_s$}{\mathcal P}lot}\xspace}
\( \sPlot_{\sPlot} \)
\end{document}
```

The vertical gap of `\DDbar` can be further tailored by playing with the -1.5pt parameter.

For the `\sPlot`, I made it so that it will work as expected in `\subscriptstyle` as well as `\textstyle`, if that is important to you.

[image]