# Removing hyperref for acronym starred commands

Tags: hyperref, acronyms, links, starred-version

In the acronym package, the starred commands \ac* and \acp* omit the acronym from the list of acronyms with option "printonlyused". My problem is that acronyms inserted like this are still hyperref links in PDFs created with pdflatex. I would like to have link-free acronyms if they are inserted with the starred commands and thus are not in the acronym table. How would I do this?

In the example below, pdflatex creates three pages, a dummy page 1, the acronym table on page 2 and two acronyms used on page 3. The first acronym correctly links to the acronym table. However, the starred command also is a hyperref. In my trials, all starred commands produced hyperref links to page 1, which has nothing to do with acronyms at all.

```
\documentclass{article}

\PassOptionsToPackage{printonlyused}{acronym}
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
the initial page

\newpage
the acronym page

\begin{acronym}
  \acro{AAA}{Aaa Abb Acc}
  \acro{TMN}{This Means Nothing}
\end{acronym}

\newpage
\ac{AAA}
\ac*{TMN}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For starred versions of its commands `acronym` calls `\AC@starredtrue`. We can use this to redefine `\AC@hyperlink` to only produce a hyperlink if a non-starred version is used. Without `hyperref` `\AC@hyperlink` essentially is the same as `\@secondoftwo` and with `hyperref` it is `\let` to `\hyperlink` at begin document. This means the redefinition should be done with the `\AtBeginDocument` hook.

The following definition lets `\AC@hyperlink` use `\@secondoftwo` in starred versions and `\hyperlink` in the non-starred versions.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[printonlyused]{acronym}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \renewcommand*\AC@hyperlink{%
    \ifAC@starred
      \expandafter\@secondoftwo
    \else
      \expandafter\hyperlink
    \fi
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
the initial page

\newpage
the acronym page

\begin{acronym}
  \acro{AAA}{Aaa Abb Acc}
  \acro{TMN}{This Means Nothing}
\end{acronym}

\newpage
\ac{AAA}
\ac*{TMN}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! This is what I wanted. In your description you say "Without hyperref `\AC@hyperlink` essentially is the same as `\@secondoftwo`". Are there any side effects associated with the 'essentially' that I need to know about to avoid them?

Comment: @KlausKopec no I don't think so. `\@secondoftwo` is defined with `\long` and `\AC@hyperlink` isn't. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1057/5049 for background on this

Comment: can this easily be made into a patch for the sty file so that I can forward it as suggestion to the package maintainer?

Comment: If you refer to this question the package maintainer should be able to adapt it easily enough if he wants to

Comment: I realize that, but unfortunately he seems to have lost interest in the package. He literally said that he'll not do it unless a patch is submitted. Maybe the package ist best abandoned in that case in favor of glossaries or s.th. similar. Thank you for your help!