# Disable acronym package hyperlink for section titles

Tags: hyperref, acronyms

I am using the acronym package in my thesis and creating a table of acronyms in the process.
Throughout the thesis the acronyms are hyperlinked back to the table.

However, I don't want acronyms in sections titles to be linked as well because this creates a weird link within the ToC and also within page headers.

Can I redefine the hyperref macro for the `\chapter`, `\section`, `\subsection` environments so that it won't link them?
And how? ([This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/165507/removing-hyperref-for-acronym-starred-commands) has it document wide for the \ac* commands)

### MWE

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\title      {Example Thesis}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter*{Definitions and Abbreviations}
\begin{acronym}
  \acro{RF}{Radio Frequency}
  \acro{PA}{power amplifier}
  \acro{WPAN}{wireless personal area networks}
\end{acronym}
\mainmatter
\chapter{\acs{RF} Communication}
\acf{RF} Communication can be used to transfer information between devices in \ac{WPAN}.
\end{document}
```

[image: Double links when acronyms in the contents page]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here a new command `\acrNoHyperlink{<acr command>}{<acr argument>}` is provided. It creates a new group, locally disables the acronym hyperlink, then runs `<acr command>{<acr argument>}`.

```tex
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\title{Example Thesis}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand\acrNoHyperlink[2]{%
  % to avoid warning "Token not allowed in a PDF string"
  \texorpdfstring{%
    \begingroup
    \disableAcronymHyperlink
    #1{#2}%
    \endgroup
  }{#1{#2}}%
}

\newcommand{\disableAcronymHyperlink}{%
  % copied from acronym.sty, lines 125--128
  \def\AC@hyperlink##1##2{##2}%
  \def\AC@hyperref[##1]##2{##2}%
  \def\AC@hypertarget##1##2{##2}%
  \def\AC@phantomsection{}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter*{Definitions and Abbreviations}
\begin{acronym}
  \acro{RF}{Radio Frequency}
  \acro{PA}{power amplifier}
  \acro{WPAN}{wireless personal area networks}
\end{acronym}
\mainmatter

\chapter{\acrNoHyperlink{\acs}{RF} Communication}
\acf{RF} Communication can be used to transfer information between devices in \ac{WPAN}.
\newpage a
\end{document}
```

See images of output showing chapter title in toc, text and header.
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Is there anyway to automatically use this command in the `chapter` `subsection` environment?

Comment: @EdL It is doable, but need to hack into internals of sectioning commands. That will cause potential compatibility problems.