# Text always on the right

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I am trying to create a macro which always places the text in its argument on the right side of the line and then the line should end.

For example:

```
Left-Text \mymacro{Right-Text}
```

should have text on the left and then when the text is done `$\box$` should be placed on the right, but on the same line (as long as it fits).

I have tried

```
\newcommand{\mymacro}[1]{\hfill \mbox{#1}}
```

which works fine provided that Right-Text fits on the last line of Left-Text.

However, if Right-Text gets moved to a new line then it appears on the left side.

For example:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\begin{document}
Doesn't work 

Left Text 0123456789 Left Text 0123456789 Left Text 0123456789
\mymacro{Right Text} 

Works

Left Text 0123456789 Left Text 0123456789 Left Text 0123456789 Left Text 0123456789
\mymacro{Right Text} 

Works

Left Text 0123456789 Left Text 0123456789
\mymacro{Right Text} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The star form of `\hspace` avoids to get canceled at the start of a new line:

```
\newcommand*{\mymacro}[1]{\hspace*{\fill}\mbox{#1}\penalty-9999\relax}
```

The penalty allows a line break, but it does not force one (-10000) to avoid an underfull `\hbox` warning, if the paragraph ends after `\mymacro`.

Comment: Thanks! This seems to work perfectly. Out of curiosity, what is the difference between \newcommand* and \newcommand?

Comment: @NateAckerman: TeX complains, if the argument contains empty lines (`\par` tokens). Since the text for `\mymacro` is intended to be a small part of a paragraph, TeX can earlier complain, if the closing argument brace has been forgotten.

Comment: Thanks that is helpful. I was also curious about the more general differences between these commands. But I will ask this as a question.

Comment: @NateAckerman: [What's the difference between \newcommand and \newcommand*?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1050/16967)

Comment: Thanks. I found that link as I was about to write my question:)