# "Good" command names for typesetting matrices and vectors

Tags: macros, best-practices

I usually add

```
\newcommand{\M}[1]{\bm{#1}}                  % Matrix
\newcommand{\V}[1]{\boldsymbol{\mathbf{#1}}} % Vector
```

to my preambles. Short command names because I use them very often. Is this considered a proper or correct way to do matrix/vector typesetting? (Not the typesetting itself, but the commands used.)

Comment: Do you know [`vector`](http://ctan.org/pkg/vector) package?

Answer (score 3):

It does not matter, what commands you are taking. If they are already defined for something else, you will notice that soon. And you can always check by typing `\show\M` in your document. Have a look in your `.log` then.

However, I would not recommend such short macros. First point: The longer, the less likelihood of duplications. Second point: It gets much easier to read for other (and sometimes even for you, if you look in older documents).

I tend to use three characters at least. As you use upper case her, this would mean just one key stroke more for my solution. Please see my MWE!

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bm}
\newcommand*{\mat}[1]{\bm{#1}} % everybody understands "mat" and it's easy to type. Use a star here (http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1050)!
\renewcommand*{\vec}[1]{\mathbf{#1}} % \vec is the typical command in LaTeX. I would redefine it. Like this, others will be able to copy parts of your code and to reuse them with the 'normal' arrow on top of vectors.

\begin{document}
$\vec{v}\mat{A}$
\end{document}
```

The `\boldsymbol` was kind of redundant here. I deleted it. Maybe you have to show us some compilable code, if you really needed that in the first place.

My own recommendation for those two command would be, to use `\bm` for both. They are both variables and should therefore be set italic.

Comment: Thank you. I agree to the length thing.

The combination `\boldsymbol\mathbf` is to make vectors upright bold. Only `\mathbf`gives non-bold greek letters.