# Wrapping a length

Tags: macros, lengths

I've cobbled together the `\basis` macro which sets and gets a hidden/internal length `\b@sis`. It is meant to work as follows :

1. Calling `\basis` returns the value of `\b@sis`
2. Calling `\basis{}` sets `\b@sis` to the default value (The current font size `\f@size`) and
3. Calling `\basis{1ex}` sets the `\b@sis` to the specified length.

2 and 3 work but 1 does not always return the value as expected. I can't use `\basis` within TikZ as a length for instance nor can I show it's value using `\the\basis` or `\showthe\basis`. I also tried prefixing `\expandafter`to the previous two "the" commands with no effect. Below is the code I have so far

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{luatex85}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{xifthen}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\makeatletter
\newlength{\b@sis}
\newlength{\length}
\setlength{\length}{2pt}
\setlength{\b@sis}{2pt}
\ProvideDocumentCommand{\basis}{g}{%
 \IfNoValueTF{#1}{%
  \b@sis}{%
  \ifthenelse{\isempty{#1}}%
  {\setlength{\b@sis}{\f@size pt}%
   \setlength{\length}{\f@size pt}}%
  {\setlength{\b@sis}{#1}%
   \setlength{\length}{#1}}}}%
\newcommand{\showbasis}{\the\b@sis}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|l|r|c|c|}                                                   % The following calls fail
\toprule
No response  & \basis        \showbasis & \tikz \draw circle(0.5*\length);            \\%& \tikz \draw circle(0.5*\basis); \\
\midrule
Sets default & \basis{}      \showbasis & \basis{}\tikz \draw circle(0.5*\length);    \\%& \tikz \draw circle(0.5*\basis); \\
\midrule
Sets Value   & \basis{1ex}   \showbasis & \basis{1ex}\tikz \draw circle(0.5*\length); \\%& \tikz \draw circle(0.5*\basis); \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

its output looks as follows

[image]

My belief is that the `\IfNoValueTF` is not being expanded when there is no argument and that the expected length not returned. Is there some means of expanding it to return the internal length or is there perhaps a better means fordoing this.

I see `\ProvideDocumentCommand` allows for an `l` argument, perhaps I should be using this within my definition ? e.g. is there a change `\basis` is reading ahead to the first non-whitespace character, the `xparse` manual implies this might be the case.

**Update**

Egreg clearly has the better solution but I only saw it after David Carlisle responded and I had messed about with it some more. The interface I got to used `\basis` and `\basis[VALUE]` to set the value and `\basis*` to retrieve it. This is really bad practice though and is certainly not [what star is for](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1057/14593).

```
\ProvideDocumentCommand{\basis}{s o}{%
 \IfBooleanTF{#1}
  {\the\b@sis}
  {\IfNoValueTF{#2}{%
    \setlength{\b@sis}{\f@size pt}%
    \setlength{\length}{\f@size pt}}
   {\setlength{\b@sis}{#2}%
    \setlength{\length}{#2}}}
  }%
```

Comment: Do you mean I should use `\IfNoValueTF{\the#1}{...}{...}` or  `\IfNoValueTF{#1}{\the\b@sis}{...}` ? I just tried both, uncommenting the `\tikz ... circle(\b@sis);` parts and compiling the file. The first dies with `missing number treated as zero`. The latter with `Missing \endcsname inserted` and a hint, `\l__xpars_processor_int`, it fails in xparse.

Comment: although it could be fixed, I'd strongly advise against that user interface as it breaks all latex syntax guidelines. `{}` should be mandatory arguments, no standard latex command sometimes takes `{}` and sometimes not ('g' is something of an aberration intended for experimenting with interfaces not matching latex2e) , also it is rather strange to use the same command to both set and retrieve the length. Why not have `\setbasis` that takes an argument and `\basis` to retrieve the current value that does not take an argument?

Comment: Hmm... I'll commit to the `\setbasis` and `\basis` interface, but I am curious as to how `\basis` might substitute for `\length`. I'm starting to get a grip on writing my own macros, for quite some time they've largely been an enigma to me, I think it's due to a lack of understanding of the TeX primitives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A command defined with an optional `g` argument is not expandable, so you cannot use `\basis` without argument in an expansion context, such as

```
\draw circle(0.5*\basis)
```

It's surely better, as suggested, to split the calls between setting the variable and using it. And you can use the full power of `expl3` to get more efficient code.

```
\documentclass[border=4pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{luatex85}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\dim_new:N \l_carel_basis_dim
\dim_set:Nn \l_carel_basis_dim { 2pt }

\NewDocumentCommand{\setbasis}{O{\use:c {f@size} pt}}
 {
  \dim_set:Nn \l_carel_basis_dim { #1 }
 }

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\basis}{}{\dim_use:N \l_carel_basis_dim}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{lrcc}
\toprule
Initial value & \basis & \tikz \draw circle(0.5*\basis); \\
\midrule
Sets default & \setbasis\basis & \setbasis\tikz \draw circle(0.5*\basis); \\
\midrule
Sets Value   & \setbasis[1ex]\basis & \setbasis[1ex]\tikz \draw circle(0.5*\basis); \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The posted code runs without error and produces what I'd expect, however you do not say what  you expect it to do.

The user interface using the same command to both set and retrieve is very confusing and perhaps that is the source of the confusion.

In the second column in the 2nd and 3rd rows you set the length but in the first row you have the rather odd construct

```
\basis        \showbasis
```

`\basis` expands to a use of the internal length and `\showbasis`  expands to `\the` applied to that length.

if you change it to

```
\basis        \showbasis\showbasis
```

so if `\b@sis` is 2pt as it is set initially then

```
\basis        \showbasis
```

is

```
\b@sis        \the\b@sis
```

which expands to

```
 \b@sis 2pt
```

so sets `\b@sis` to the value 2pt that it had already.

Adding a second `\showbasis` as I did prints the 2pt to the table,

[image]

then you see that the value is 2pt hence the small circle.

and if you just have `\basis` on the cell on its own you get a missing number error as it is the assignment of a length, with no supplied value.

Comment: That makes far more sense, I assumed that due to `g` a `\basis` on it's own would utilize the default value. I also didn't realize I was looping the assignment. Does `\basis` in  `\tikz circle (\basis);` try to set the value rather then use it ?

Comment: I awarded the answer to Egreg but wanted to thank you for your assistance.