# Align chapter title to the right

Tags: titlesec

I have the following code:

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{titlesec, blindtext, color}

\definecolor{gray75}{gray}{0.75}

\newcommand{\hsp}{\hspace{20pt}}

\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\Huge\bfseries}{\thechapter\hsp\textcolor{gray75}{|}\hsp}{0pt}{\Huge\bfseries}
```

---

I would like to align the chapter title to the right. Any help? This is my current output:

[image]

Comment: Only the title or including the number?

Comment: Your `\hsp` macro doesn't have to be long. You might change the `\newcommand` to `\newcommand*`.

Comment: Including the number. I'm new at this. What's the difference between \newcommand and \newcommand*?

Comment: You might take a look [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1050/whats-the-difference-between-newcommand-and-newcommand) for an explanation on the difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the dedicated command, `\filleft` in the second mandatory argument of `\titleformat` if you want the whole set chapter number+ chapter title to be right aligned:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{titlesec, blindtext, color}

\definecolor{gray75}{gray}{0.75}

\newcommand{\hsp}{\hspace{20pt}}

\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\filleft\Huge\bfseries}{\thechapter\hsp\textcolor{gray75}{|}\hsp}{0pt}{\Huge\bfseries}

    \begin{document}

    \chapter{Introdução}

\section{As Doenças Cerebrovasculares}
\blindtext

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The following might give your desired result:

```
\documentclass[]{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{titlesec, blindtext, color, pbox}

\definecolor{gray75}{gray}{0.75}

\newcommand*{\hsp}{\hspace{20pt}}
\newcommand{\titlepbox}[1]{\pbox[t]{0.7\textwidth}{#1}}

\titleformat{\chapter}[block]{\Huge\bfseries}{\hfill\thechapter\hsp\textcolor{gray75}{|}\hsp}{0pt}{\Huge\bfseries\titlepbox}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Foo}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]

You might tweak the `\titlepbox` command (e.g. insert a `\raggedleft` or `\raggedright` infront of the `#1`) for some more options.

Also the maximum width (currently at `0.7\textwidth`) of the headings (excluding the number and vertical line) can be changed.

The `[t]` controls vertical placement -- `[b]` would make the number bottom aligned to the heading.