# Change caption for \listoffigures

Tags: table-of-contents, floats

How to change the caption of the `\listoffigures` command?

```
\listoffigures[list of pictures] #something like that doesn't work
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [this site](https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?p=9317) it can be done by using `\addto\captions<language>{\renewcommand\listfigurename{<Your title>}}` where `<language>` has to be replaced with the language loaded via `babel` for your document (for english that would be `\addto\captionsenglish`).
Alternatively you can issue a `\renewcommand*\listfigurename{<Your title>}` **after** `\begin{document}` but **before** `\listoffigures`.

Comment: whats the maning of the *? its working without as well, but I'm curious.

Comment: @Tim4497 see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1050/whats-the-difference-between-newcommand-and-newcommand - in short: yes it would also work without the star