# Why the * in \newcommand*?

Tags: math-mode, macros, amsmath, preamble, robust-commands

I saw several examples of user defined macros using **\newcommand** (without the `*`), and examples with **\newcommand***.  Trying both in my test documents doesn't show any difference.  So why the asterisk?  What are its functions?  Should I care about it or not?

Here's a simple MWE to play with, in case it is usefeull here:

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\newcommand*{\bigs}[1]{\vcenter{\hbox{\scalebox{1.25}{#1}}}} % Why the *?

\begin{document}

Blabla bla bla blabla :
    \begin{equation}
        c \, \bigs( 1 + (x - y^2)(a + b) \bigs) = \tfrac{3}{4}.
    \end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\newcommand` uses `\long\def` and `\newcommand*` only `\def`, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1057.

Comment: Thanks.  So my question is a duplicate.

Comment: From cat to cat: yes. ;-)