# Different between \def and \long\def and where to use

Tags: tex-core, definition

Please excuse if my question is silly....

May I know what's the difference between `\def` and `\long\def` and where to use `\long\def`

Thanks....

Comment: Unless you are a programmer, you should use neither, as they are plain TeX commands. In LaTeX, use `\newcommand` or `\NewDocumentCommand` instead. But the difference is that `\long\def` allows the argument to contain paragraph breaks.

Comment: `\newcommand` is the LaTeX version of `\long\def`, whereas `\newcommand*` is the LaTeX version of `\def`.

Comment: The answer is here https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1057/2288

Comment: Thanks a lot to all.....