# understanding mistake: paragraph indentation in newcommand environment

Tags: errors, environments, alignment

I am fairly new to using Tex, and am encountering the following error that I don't understand.

I define the following new environment to list selection criteria for a job:

```
\newcommand*{\selcrit}[2]
{ 
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*]
\item\textbf{#1}
\end{itemize}

\vspace{-7pt}

\begin{adjustwidth}{1.5em}{0pt}
#2
\end{adjustwidth}

\vspace{5pt}
}
```

if I try to include an indentation in a new paragraph beginning, by leaving an empty line in argument #2, I get the following error: "Paragraph ended before \selcrit was complete."

below is an example of a bit of code that produces the above error.

```
\selcrit{test}{
test

test    
}
```

any thoughts would be much appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Try with `\newcommand` - not `\newcommand*` - instead.

Comment: Thanks Werner -- that indeed fixed it. can you explain to me what the problem was?

Comment: `\newcommand*` creates commands that are not `\long`, i.e. cannot accept paragraph tokens. There is more info here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1050.

Comment: Thanks, plante and Stefan. learned something new.