# Memoir and Problems with Chapter and Appendix Styling

Tags: chapters, memoir, appendices

I am writing PhD thesis and I have some guidelines put forth by the university that I must conform to. I have mostly nailed it using the memoir package by following the thesis example memoir provides. Please note, I don't have the option of changing these guidelines. Also the university does provides a template but it is quite old and redefines stuff like `\year` which breaks compatibility with a lot of packages.

One area I could use help with is in the Chapter styling. I have a specific amount of space I need before and after and the entire thing needs to be on one line. It should look like for example "1.0    Introduction" all on one line (centered and bolded).

I have achieved this with the following.

```
\renewcommand{\chapterheadstart}{} 
\renewcommand{\afterchapternum}{}
\renewcommand{\chapnamefont}{\centering\bfseries} 
\renewcommand{\chaptitlefont}{\centering\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\chapnumfont}{\centering\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{}
\renewcommand{\chapternamenum}[1]{#1.0\space\space\space\space}
```

which yields

[image]

However this seems to mess up the Appendix numbering which now looks like

[image]

I would prefer it to say "Appendix A Supplemental" without the `.0`.

I'd appreciate any advice on how this could be achieved. If my attempt at chapter styling could be done better I'd appreciate any feedback there as well.

Here is a MWE.

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,oneside]{memoir}

\usepackage{lipsum}

% ================
% Chapter Styling
% ================
\renewcommand{\chapterheadstart}{}
\renewcommand{\afterchapternum}{}
\renewcommand{\chapnamefont}{\centering\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\chaptitlefont}{\centering\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\chapnumfont}{\centering\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{}
\renewcommand{\chapternamenum}[1]{#1.0\space\space\space\space}
% ================


\begin{document}

\mainmatter
\chapter{Introduction}
\lipsum[1]
\appendix
\chapter{Supplemental}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code.

`memories` uses `\ifanappendix` to test if the number is an appendix.

[image: a]

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,oneside]{memoir}

\usepackage{lipsum}

% ================
% Chapter Styling
% ================
\renewcommand{\chapterheadstart}{}
\renewcommand{\afterchapternum}{}
\renewcommand{\chapnamefont}{\centering\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\chaptitlefont}{\centering\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\chapnumfont}{\centering\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{}
\renewcommand{\chapternamenum}[1]{\ifanappendix \space #1\else #1.0\fi} % changed <<<<<<<<<<
\renewcommand*{\afterchapternum}{\space\space\space\space}% added <<<<<<<<<<<<
% ================


\begin{document}
    
    \mainmatter
    \chapter{Introduction}
    \lipsum[1]
    \chapter{Another chapter}
    \lipsum[1]
    \appendix
    \chapter{Supplemental}
    \lipsum[1]
    \chapter{Extra Supplement}
    \lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! One question though, why did you use `\renewcommand*` instead of `\renewcommand`?

Comment: @Nukesub It probably won't make any difference in this case, but see [https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1054/161015]. I assume that `memoir` uses `\renewcommand*` in its code for the same reason.