# What is the preferred way of defining a TikZ constant?

Tags: tikz-pgf, best-practices

I'm drawing a TikZ figure and am going to need a couple of constant that I could easily change between compilations, e.g. a main radius, a proportion, a number of lines, etc. What is the preferred way of defining these?

It's not just one `\draw` command, so I suppose I can't use `let`.

Comment: I would use `\newcommand*{\Name}{<value>}` to declare it so that you can be sure it is not already been defined elsewhere.  Definitely do **not** use `\let` -- it is **not** for this purpose.

Comment: Do you plan to adjust these from the command line for multiple runs? Or is this `tikzpicture` included in another document and if so, do you want to adjust them from that document?

Comment: @PeterGrill: Thanks. The `tikzpicture` is included from another document, but I only need to change the constants in the document containing the `tikzpicture` (the deepest document).

Comment: @PeterGrill: There is a `let` operation in TikZ, I guess the OP doesn’t mean TeX’s `\let` macro.

Comment: @Tobi: Ok, that's probably what the OP meant. And yes, the TeX `\let` is different than the TiKZ `let`.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

### Using `\newcommand` and `\pgfmathsetmacro`:

Since you are only planning on changing the parameter within the deepest `.tex` file containing the `tikzpicture`, I would use `\newcommand*{\Name}{}%` to set the values and the just use `\Name` to access them.

However, if the value of some of the parameters are mathematically computed from another, then I would recommend using `\pgfmathsetmacro{\NewName}{}`. For example:

```
\newcommand*{\Diameter}{3.0}%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\Radius}{\Diameter/2}%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\Circumference}{2*pi*\Radius}%
```

This will be very useful when the calculation is a bit more complex.

However, should you want to consider the ability to change them from the parent document, you could instead use `\providecommand{}{}` in the `tikzpicture` document instead to set the parameter. This will then allow for the possibility that you could change the parameter in the parent document. One downside of this approach is that there is a risk that the value is defined somewhere else also no error will be triggered in the `tikzpicture`.

### Using `\pgfmathsetnewmacro`:

As pointed out in the comments `\pgfmathsetmacro` uses a `\def` so no error is produced if you are overwriting an existing macro name.  So, instead you could use `\pgfmathsetnewmacro` as defined below -- this issues a `\newcommand` to check that the macro does not already exist, before calling `\pgfmathsetmacro`:

```
\newcommand*{\pgfmathsetnewmacro}[2]{%
    \newcommand*{#1}{}% Error if already defined
    \pgfmathsetmacro{#1}{#2}%
}%
```

If you are defining the values within the `tikzpicture` and are not worried about overriding any previously defined ones, then you can use `\def` and `\pgfmathsetmacro`.

### Update: Problems with using `\def`:

The comments suggest that if you define these constants **within** the `tikzpicture` environment, any case of accidentally overwriting an existing macro via a `\def` or `\pgfmathsetmacro` will *not* result in any problems outside of the `tikzpicture` as the re-definitions would only be local to the `tikzpicture` environment.  This is **NOT** entirely accurate, as it **can** result in problems inside the `tikzpicture` environment, as I just discovered after several hours of debugging.

With the *wrong* thinking that there is no problems in using `\def` within a local scope, I decide to change the hard to read (and hard to modify if additional parameters are added at the beginning) macros such as:

```
\newcommand*{\DrawXAxis}[3][]{%
    \draw [ultra thick, #1] (#2,0) -- (#3,0)%
}%
```

to something like this:

```
\newcommand*{\DrawXAxisReadable}[3][]{%
    \def\XAxisStyle{#1}
    \def\XAxisMin{#2}
    \def\XAxisMax{#3}
    \draw [ultra thick, \XAxisStyle] (\XAxisMin,0) -- (\XAxisMax,0)%
}%
```

thinking that there is no problem if I overwrite `\XAxisMin` within this macro as I don't need what ever has been set previously and it will be restored anyway upon the end of this macro.

Well, this is ok in *most* cases -- but **not ok** if some parent macro had defined `\XAxisMin` and had passed it to this macro as a parameter.  The code below illustrates this. It compiles just fine as is, but if you un comment the last `tikzpicture` then `pdflatex` seems to be stuck in an infinite loop.

---

### Test Code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

%\def\Diameter{}% Error from \newcommand if this is uncommented
%\def\Radius{}% Error from \pgfmathsetnewmacro if this is uncommented
%\def\Circumference{}% Error from \pgfmathsetnewmacro if this is uncommented


% This bascially automates a \newcommand{<name>}{} to ensure
% that a command with the given <name> does not already exist
\newcommand*{\pgfmathsetnewmacro}[2]{%
    \newcommand*{#1}{}% Error if already defined
    \pgfmathsetmacro{#1}{#2}%
}%

\begin{document}
\newcommand*{\Diameter}{3.0}%

\pgfmathsetnewmacro{\Radius}{\Diameter/2}%
\pgfmathsetnewmacro{\Circumference}{2*pi*\Radius}%

\newcommand{\Origin}{(0,0)}%

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw \Origin circle (\Radius);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Code: Problem in using `\def` within `tikzpicture`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand*{\XAxisMin}{0}%
\newcommand*{\XAxisMax}{5}%

\newcommand*{\DrawXAxis}[3][]{%
    \draw [ultra thick, #1] (#2,0) -- (#3,0)%
}%

\newcommand*{\DrawXAxisReadable}[3][]{%
    \def\XAxisStyle{#1}
    \def\XAxisMin{#2}
    \def\XAxisMax{#3}
    \draw [ultra thick, \XAxisStyle] (\XAxisMin,0) -- (\XAxisMax,0)%
}%

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \DrawXAxis[black]{\XAxisMin}{\XAxisMax};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \DrawXAxisReadable[blue]{0}{5};
\end{tikzpicture}

%%% Un comment this to see the problem
%\begin{tikzpicture}
%   \DrawXAxisReadable[red]{\XAxisMin}{\XAxisMax};
%\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I prefer the shorter `\def\xx{2.0}` which should harmless since I use it inside the `tikzpicuture` environment (group). The definition is only valid inside the group an won’t cause conflict outside. Certainly this will only work if one needs the parameters in one picture.

Comment: @Tobi: Personal preference I guess. I often put my constant definitions outside the `tikzpicture`, so prefer `\newcommand*{}{}` as it is safer. And if there are many of these to define, copy-paste is faster anyway.

Comment: What are the safety issues with `\def`?

Comment: @Nazia: `\newcommand` will produce an error if you attempt to redefine an existing name, `\def` will not. See [What is the difference between \def and \newcommand?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/655/what-is-the-difference-between-def-and-newcommand)

Comment: @ Peter: Surly, this is my preference … :-)

Comment: @PeterGrill TikZ works with plain TeX and LaTeX, and `\pgfmathsetmacro` uses `\edef`. Then if you want something quicker in loops I think in this case `\def` is more efficient (look at the def of `\pgfmathsetmacro` . And in a group, macros are local, so `\def` can be used instead of `newcommand`.

Comment: @Altermundus: Have updated to provide a `\pgfmathsetnewmacro{<name>}{<expression>}` that issues an error if the `<name>` is already defined, also noted that if one is not concerned about over writing existing names, then `\def` is just fine.

Comment: @Tobi: Updated to show that there is a possible problem in using `\def`.

Comment: @PeterGrill: Ok, thanks. I see the problem but it makes no difference if I use `\renewcommand` instead of `\def` …

Comment: @Tobi: Well with `\renewcommand` you **know** you are redefining something, with `\def` you don't.

Comment: @PeterGrill: But with `\def` I know that I _define_ a variable (in the current scope/group) ;-) So this decision is subjective since both have the same problem as shown in your example.

Comment: @Tobi: I don't use `\renewcommand`, but `\newcommand` to be safe.

Comment: Yes, but the example you give to show the disadvantage of `\def` has the same problem with `\(re)newcommand` ;-) The benefit of using `\newcommand` is that it gives an error if your variable macro already exists.

Comment: @Tobi: I think you should post an answer to summarize what you are recommending, as it might be confusing to someone who comes across this question.  I am recommending **not** using `\def`, and **not** using `\renewcommand`.

Comment: @PeterGrill: I added my answer … But I think that your example “Code: Problem in using \def within tikzpicture:” doesn’t show the disadvantage of `\def` against `\newcommand` since it produces the same error when I replace `\def` by `\newcommand` ;-)

Comment: @Tobi: If you use `\newcommand` in the `Problem with \def` (with the last one uncommented) then you get a nice error that explains exactly what the problem is. With `\def` it just hangs and you don't know what went wrong. It took my quite some time to diagnose my problem as it was nested several macros deep..

Comment: Another note on `\def`: don't use it for "complex expressions", only for "constant literal" https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/235444/tikz-how-to-define-a-constant-and-then-use-it-in-drawing#comment1605472_235446

Answer (score 7):

### Using `\def`

I normally prefer the shorter `\def` than `\newcommand`. **The problem is, that** `\def` doesn’t check wether **the macro** already exist, so it’s **maybe overwritten**. But I use the `\def`initions only *inside* `{tikzpicture}` and for a possible overwriting only exists in the current group of `{tikzpicture}`

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \def\radius{1cm}
   \draw circle (\radius);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

In the above example `\radius` is only defined inside of `{tikzpicture}` and can only be used inside of it.

The next example shows that `\def` maybe produce an undesired result

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \def\bfseries{1mm}
   \draw [line width=\bfseries] circle (2cm);
   \node {\bfseries That's the problem.};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Using `\newcommand`

If I need a global variable I prefer `\newcommand` since it gives an error if I try to use an already existing macro name.

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand\radius{1cm}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \draw circle (\radius);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
   \draw [red] circle (\radius);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The same example as the second one in “Using `\def`” but with `\newcommand`. If we now try to use an existing command (`\bfseries`) as TikZ variable we get the error message that `\bfseries` is already defined. So the user must decide wether to redefine it or use an other name which is the recommend way in this case.

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \newcommand\bfseries{1mm}
   \draw [line width=\bfseries] circle (2cm);
   \node {\bfseries That's the problem.};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @PeterGrill: This is my answer. What do you think about it?

Comment: I don't think your 2nd example shows a problem. One would do that if they did not know (or did not want) to use `\bfseries`, and hence the correct result was produced.

Comment: @PeterGrill: I guess I used the wrong words … with “problem” I mean that there will be a conflict because `\bfseries` is defined already and cant be uses with `\newcommand` so the user will be warned that he maybe does something he don’t want (overwrite `\bfseries` assuming he doesn’t know that it exist already). So the LaTeX gives the right result (error message) but it’s a problem from the users point of view. Hope that I made more clear what I wanted to say :-)